# What Unicode Font is Best Suited for Math Symbols using Font-Locking under Emacs?

Tags: emacs, auctex, unicode-math

I recently installed Emacs + AucTeX on MS Windows using the pre-configured binary available from this [CTAN webpage](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/win32-emacs-auctex) and everything works quite well with the latest MikTeX installation and Ghostscript 8 (both of which need to be installed separately).  This is by far the easiest method I have found for getting all of these programs installed and working together under Windows.

One of Emacs' many useful features is "font-locking," which allows certain character sequences in the document to display on-screen as user-specified Unicode symbols.  For example, typing the sequence **\alpha** in the document can be displayed (using the font-locking mechanism) as the Greek letter form *alpha* on the screen (but not stored as such in the file on disk) if this symbol is available in the font being used for this purpose under Emacs.  This capability is very useful when one cannot directly use the Unicode document encoding format for the file on disk (say for compatibility reasons) but still wants to see the Unicode glyphs that correspond to various LaTeX symbols when displaying the document in the Emacs editor window.

An older package that enables this instant on-screen translation of sequence names to corresponding Unicode glyphs under Emacs is called x-symbol.  A more recent package (available on this reddit [page](http://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/l5yt0/introducting_latexprettysymbolsel/)) that appears to accomplish the same thing is called *latex-pretty-symbols.el*, which works quite well with the above-described installation.

Unfortunately, many Unicode fonts that are available under Windows appear to support only a meager subset of the LaTeX math symbols that one routinely uses, including the fonts suggested by Xah Lee on his [Unicode emacs blog](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/emacs_unicode_fonts.html) and on this Penn State [webpage](http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/bylanguage/math.html).

**Question:**

What options are there for Unicode fonts under Emacs (MS Windows) that contain all of the routinely used LaTeX math symbols?

One would think that perhaps the Computer Modern fonts themselves might exist in some form (encoding + format) that would allow them to be used from within Emacs, and if so has anyone had success using them for this purpose?

How about the [STIX fonts](http://www.stixfonts.org/)?

The Cambria Math fonts can be used from within Emacs, but subscripts and superscripts do not display properly when typing them inside math blocks.  Is it somehow possible to configure AucTeX to position sub/superscripts vertically in a visually acceptable manner when using Cambria Math, or is the format of this relatively new font from Microsoft somehow incompatible with what Emacs + AucTeX can handle under Windows at the moment?

**Edit:** The information on this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624229/cambria-math-big-top-and-bottom-margin) helps explain why Emacs is having trouble rendering the Cambria Math font.  Apparently Microsoft is utilizing extensions to the OpenType format for math symbols that Emacs (as well as various legacy apps like Word 2000) cannot properly handle.  A more detailed explanation is provided by Murray Sargent on his [blog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/murrays/high-fonts-and-math-fonts).

Comment: Do you know the [Computer Modern Unicode fonts](http://cm-unicode.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: @matth:  The fonts on this page appear to be packaged for X Windows.  CTAN lists a package that provides Type 1 conversions of the original METAFONT Computer Modern font files using a program called TeXTrace.  My understanding is that these converted fonts can be used by LaTeX but cannot be installed at the OS level in MS Windows in order to be used in other applications because of encoding issues.  Is this correct?

Comment: @stackexchanger: there is more than one autotraced type 1 version of the cm fonts on ctan.  the best by a mile is now inclded in the ams fonts.  textrace, while good, requires a lot of extra effort; the ams fonts cm were developed by y&y (now extinct) using a private autotracer and lots of elbow grease.  all of these fonts are encoded using knuth's encodings, however.  the cm-unicode fonts use cm glyphs to populate a unicode font space; i would expect cm-unicode to work with widnoze, but i've never tried.  (i don't often try anything with widnoze...)

Comment: @StackExchanger The CM Unicode font on sourceforge can be installed under Windows and then be used by all applications. I use them in Word and Inkscape

Comment: @matth:  Thanks ... cm-unicode on sourceforge looks like what I need.  By any chance do you know if this [version](http://cm-unicode.sourceforge.net/) of the fonts is the same high-quality one produced by Y&Y referenced in the comment above, and if not, where they can be found?

Comment: @StackExchanger The CM fonts on sf.net "were converted from metafont sources using mftrace with autotrace backend and fontforge (former pfaedit)." I have never heard of Y&Y and don't know where to find their fonts, sorry. If you find these fonts somwhere in ttf or (even better) otf format, you can use them on OS level in Windows. You could also check your Tex directory, there are some otf fonts.

Comment: @matth Would you like to turn your comments into an answer, since this seems to be what the OP wanted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested by egreg, I will turn my comments into an answer to at least part of your question:

> One would think that perhaps the **Computer Modern fonts** themselves
>   might exist in some form (encoding + format) that would allow them to
>   be used from within Emacs, and if so has anyone had success using them
>   for this purpose?

You could use the [CM-Unicode](http://cm-unicode.sourceforge.net/) fonts, which are installable under Windows on OS level and therefore usable from all applications using the system fonts. I use these fonts in Inkscape, Word and PowerPoint.

Quoting from the [CM-Unicode homepage](http://cm-unicode.sourceforge.net/):

> Computer Modern Unicode fonts were **converted from metafont sources**
>   using **mftrace** with autotrace backend and fontforge (former pfaedit).
>   Their main purpose is to create free good quality fonts for use in X
>   applications supporting many languages. Currently the fonts contain
>   glyphs from Latin1 (Metafont ec, tc, vnr), Cyrillic (lh) and Greek
>   (cbgreek when available) code sets and IPA extensions (from tipa).

You also ask about [STIX fonts](http://www.stixfonts.org/). These fonts are also available in otf format, so I would say it should be easy to install these fonts on system level.

Answer (score 3):

As of 2021, [any OpenType math font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425098/which-opentype-math-fonts-are-available) should work. New Computer Modern Math is the version of Computer Modern with the most-comprehensive Unicode coverage.

DejaVu Sans Mono is a free, fixed-width font with excellent coverage of Unicode math symbols.

Answer (score 1):

My preference is the IsabelleText font, which is, according to the [README](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/repos/isabelle/file/d5a198eb16b5/lib/fonts/README):

> assembled with FontForge (http://fontforge.sourceforge.net), 
>   composing glyphs from existing (free) fonts: Bluesky TeX 
>   fonts (scaled 222%) and Bitstream Vera Mono, with some 
>   additions from DejaVu Sans Mono and DejaVu Sans.

It's available as a `.ttf` [here](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/repos/isabelle/file/d5a198eb16b5/lib/fonts).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try the `Symbola` font which you can obtain from [this site](https://dn-works.com/ufas/).  Check this [pdf file](https://dn-works.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/UFAS-Docs/Symbola.pdf) for the symbols provided by the font.

Emacs has a default fall-back this font and it doesn't have to search through all of your installed fonts to find a glyph.  This search process can slow down Emacs significantly.