# Which OpenType Math fonts are available?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, unicode-math, opentype

What OpenType math fonts are there available for usage in TeX/LaTeX, e.g. with the `unicode-math` package?

Here is a MWE which you can use to show off the font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator\Res{Res}
\newcommand*\diff{\mathop{}\!\mathup{d}}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

%%%
% Set up you text and math fonts
%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Residue theorem]
  Let $f$ be analytic in the region $G$ except for the isolated
  singularities $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_m$. If $\gamma$ is a closed
  rectifiable curve in $G$ which does not pass through any of the
  points $a_k$ and if $\gamma\approx 0$ in $G$, then
  \[
    \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int\limits_\gamma f\Bigl(x^{\mathbf{N}\in\mathbb{C}^{N\times 10}}\Bigr)
    = \sum_{k=1}^m n(\gamma;a_k)\Res(f;a_k)\,.
  \]
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Maximum modulus]
  Let $G$ be a bounded open set in $\BbbC$ and suppose that $f$ is a
  continuous function on $G^-$ which is analytic in $G$. Then
  \[
    \max\{\, |f(z)|:z\in G^- \,\} = \max\{\, |f(z)|:z\in \partial G \,\}\,.
  \]
\end{theorem}

First some large operators both in text:
$\iiint\limits_{Q}f(x,y,z) \diff x \diff y \diff z$
and
$\prod_{\gamma\in\Gamma_{\bar{C}}}\partial(\tilde{X}_\gamma)$;\
and also on display
\[
  \iiiint\limits_{Q}f(w,x,y,z) \diff w \diff x \diff y \diff z
  \leq
  \oint_{\partial Q} f'\Biggl(\max\Biggl\{
  \frac{\Vert w\Vert}{\vert w^2+x^2\vert};
  \frac{\Vert z\Vert}{\vert y^2+z^2\vert};
  \frac{\Vert w\oplus z\Vert}{\vert x\oplus y\vert}
  \Biggr\}\Biggr)\,.
\]

\end{document}
```

Here is a similar MWE for ConTeXt.  The images in the answer will only be shown for LaTeX output but the ConTeXt output looks very similar.

```
%%%
% Set up you text and math fonts
%%%

\setupmathlabeltext[Res=Res]
\definemathcommand[Res][nolop]{\mfunctionlabeltext{Res}}
\definemathcommand[diff]{\mathop{}\!\mfunctionlabeltext{diff}}

\defineenumeration
  [theorem]
  [text={Theorem},
   style=italic,
   title=yes,
   titlestyle=normal,
   distance=0pt,
   titleleft={(},
   titleright={).~},
   alternative=serried,
   width=fit]

\starttext

  \starttheorem[title={Residue theorem}]
    Let $f$ be analytic in the region $G$ except for the isolated
    singularities $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_m$. If $\gamma$ is a closed
    rectifiable curve in $G$ which does not pass through any of the
    points $a_k$ and if $\gamma\approx 0$ in $G$, then
    \startformula
      \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int\limits_\gamma f\Bigl(x^{{\mathbf N}\in\mathbb{C}^{N\times 10}}\Bigr)
      = \sum_{k=1}^m n(\gamma;a_k)\Res(f;a_k)\,.
    \stopformula
  \stoptheorem

  \starttheorem[title={Maximum modulus}]
    Let $G$ be a bounded open set in $\mathbb{C}$ and suppose that $f$ is a
    continuous function on $G^-$ which is analytic in $G$. Then
    \startformula
      \max\{\, |f(z)|:z\in G^- \,\} = \max\{\, |f(z)|:z\in \partial G \,\}\,.
    \stopformula
  \stoptheorem

  First some large operators both in text:
  $\iiint\limits_{Q}f(x,y,z) \diff x \diff y \diff z$
  and
  $\prod_{\gamma\in\Gamma_{\bar{C}}}\partial(\tilde{X}_\gamma)$;\
  and also on display
  \startformula
    \iiiint\limits_{Q}f(w,x,y,z) \diff w \diff x \diff y \diff z
    \leq
    \oint_{\partial Q} f'\Biggl(\max\Biggl\{
    \frac{\Vert w\Vert}{\vert w^2+x^2\vert};
    \frac{\Vert z\Vert}{\vert y^2+z^2\vert};
    \frac{\Vert w\oplus z\Vert}{\vert x\oplus y\vert}
    \Biggr\}\Biggr)\,.
  \stopformula

\stoptext
```

Comment: Yep, hehe By the way you could use a software that automatically antialiases pdfs before taking screenshots, I think the would look nicer. Great job in any case.

Comment: superb effort -- added to "often referenced questions" in meta.  comment on tex gyre fonts -- the limits are awfully close to the sum, except for latin modern; i suppose this should be reported to the developers.

Comment: @barbarabeeton also there is glyph collision of ``f`` with ``|`` in ``|f(z)|`` in all four of TeX Gyre {Termes,Pagella,Schola,Bonum} Math. (and near glyph collision of again the ``f`` with the subscripted ``Q`` in bottom display, possibly because the multiple integrals look definitely text and not display style in thsse math fonts)

Comment: This question and its answer(s?) should be turned into siomething more findable and more durable than a Stack Exchange question... A TuGboat paper ? A monograph adjunction to TeXlive ?

Comment: @HenriMenke started it and wrote the template, and I ended up contributing 75% of the answer, so do you think editing it down and submitting it somewhere would be worthwhile?

Comment: @Davislor If you feel like submitting this somewhere, feel free to do so.  However, I doubt that this will be very useful in a statically printed form, because new additions come (GFS Neohellenic) and outdated fonts go or are superseded (STIX).  A publication in a form similar to http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/ would probably be way more useful.  I think we could start something in that direction.  Do you have a GitHub account?

Comment: @HenriMenke I have a couple of my projects in different languages up at https://github.com/Davislor/  Maybe take this to chat?

Comment: @HenriMenke: It may be a good idea to post ConTeXt translation of the answer an well. If no one else does it, I'll post that as a separate answer in a few weeks.

Comment: Stix is one of a better math font..

Comment: I started a repo based on this: https://github.com/ickc/latex-opentype-math-fonts

Answer (score 199, accepted):

## The TeX Gyre Fonts

### Latin Modern

This is the default font family loaded by `unicode-math`, but can also be set up explicitly.  It is an OpenType version of Latin Modern, a clone of DEK’s Computer Modern, based on Monotype Modern, and of the AMS symbol fonts.  The default fonts are therefore nearly identical to those of classic LaTeX.

This conversion is the work of the GUST project, which later created the TeX Gyre fonts from the free URW fonts, which were based on the Adobe PostScript fonts.  All of these fonts (except TeX Gyre DejaVu Math, a conversion of an existing OpenType font into a math font) have similar repertoires and features. They support all European languages as well as Romanizations of other languages.

The vast majority of the fonts on this page similarly cloned an existing font, but changed the name to avoid confusion or to comply with the license.  Some have gone through three or four iterations of this.

GUST is the Polish TeX users’ group.  Many of the people most motivated to extend existing fonts were from Southern or Eastern Europe, since fonts that already covered Western European languages and Greek letters for math were almost able to support their native languages.

```
% LaTeX
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
% ConTeXt
\setupbodyfont[modern]
```

[image: Latin Modern]

### TeX Gyre Bonum

This is a clone of Bookman.

```
% LaTeX
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Bonum}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Bonum Math}
% ConTeXt
\setupbodyfont[bonum]
```

[image: TeX Gyre Bonum]

### TeX Gyre Pagella

This is a clone of Palatino.

```
% LaTeX
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
% ConTeXt
\setupbodyfont[pagella]
```

[image: TeX Gyre Pagella]

### TeX Gyre Schola

This is a clone of Century Schoolbook.

```
% LaTeX
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Schola Math}
% ConTeXt
\setupbodyfont[schola]
```

[image: TeX Gyre Schola]

### TeX Gyre Termes

This is a clone of Times.

```
% LaTeX
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
% ConTeXt
\setupbodyfont[termes]
```

[image: TeX Gyre Termes]

### TeX Gyre DejaVu Math

This font is an extension of the DejaVu Serif font, which is based on Arev, which is based on Bitstream Vera, which is based on Bitstream Prima.

It is significantly different from the other TeX Gyre fonts, as they were conversions of legacy fonts to Unicode, and this turns an existing, comprehensive Unicode font by someone else into a math font.  The DejaVu project was started by Štěpán Roh of the Czech Republic.

```
% LaTeX
\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}
% ConTeXt
\setupbodyfont[dejavu]
```

[image: TeX Gyre DejaVu Math]

### DejaVu Math TeX Gyre

The version of the same font distributed by the [DejaVu project](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dejavu/) rather than the TeX Gyre project.

```
% LaTeX
\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}
\setmathfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{DejaVu Math TeX Gyre}
```

[image: DejaVu Math TeX Gyre]

## Other Free Fonts

### XITS

This is an fork by Khaled Hosny of the STIX font.  it was one of the first free OpenType math fonts to come in both a regular and a bold weight, meaning that `\boldmath`, `\mathversion{bold}` and `\boldsymbol` will all work with it.

```
% LaTeX
\setmainfont{XITS}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
% ConTeXt
\setupbodyfont[xits]
```

[image: XITS]

### Libertinus

Libertinus is a fork by Khaled Hosny of the Linux Libertine font family by Philipp Poll.  It comes in a bold weight, like his font XITS Math.

Dr. Hosny is also an expert on typesetting math in the Arabic script, so his fonts Libertinus Math and Amiri make excellent companions if you are writing in a language such as Arabic, Persian or Urdu.

```
% LaTeX
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
% ConTeXt
\setupbodyfont[libertinus]
```

[image: Libertinus]

### Asana Math

Asana is a close match for Palatino, and therefore its clones, such as Pagella.  You should use one of them as the text font.  If you try to make Asana the text font, you will not get either styles or ligatures.

It was created by Apostolos Syropoulos, based on Type 1 fonts by Young Ryu, and is similar in appearance to the `pxfonts` package.

```
% LaTeX
\setmainfont[Ligatures={Common,Rare,TeX}]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Asana Math}
```

[image: Asana Math with Pagella]

### STIX Two

This is the successor to the STIX font of which XITS is a clone.  It was added to CTAN, TeX Live and MikTeX in 2018.

```
% LaTeX
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
% ConTeXt
\setupbodyfont[stixtwo]
```

[image: STIX Two]

### GFS Neohellenic

This font has only minor slab serifs, making it a good choice for presentations.  It is based on the public-domain font New Hellenic, inspired by a Greek font from Renaissance Venice.

The math version was commissioned from the Greek Fonts Society by the Department of Mathematics at the University of the Aegean.

```
% LaTeX
\setmainfont{GFS Neohellenic}
\setmathfont{GFS Neohellenic Math}
% ConTeXt (no ready-made typescript available)
\definefontfamily [mainface] [serif] [Latin Modern Roman]
\definefontfamily [mainface] [sans]  [GFS Neohellenic]
\definefontfamily [mainface] [mono]  [Latin Modern Mono]
\definefontfamily [mainface] [math]  [GFS Neohellenic Math]
\setupbodyfont[mainface]
```

[image: GFS Neohellenic]

### Garamond Math

This font was added to CTAN in 2019.  It is based on EB Garamond.

```
% LaTeX
\setmainfont{EBGaramond-Regular}[
  BoldFont = EBGaramond-Bold,
  ItalicFont = EBGaramond-Italic,
  BoldItalicFont = EBGaramond-BoldItalic
]
\setmathfont{Garamond Math}[Scale=MatchUppercase]
```

[image: Garamond Math with EB Garamond]

### Fira Math

This font is based on the Fira Go sans-serif font.  It was added to CTAN in November 2018.

```
% LaTeX
\setmainfont{FiraGO}
\setmathfont{FiraMath-Regular}
```

[image: Fira Math Specimen]

### Erewhon Math

Erewhon Math is based on Utopia, via Heuristica and Erewhon.  Its math symbols are based on the `fourier` package.  It was added to CTAN in December 2019.

The recommended way to load it is with

```
\usepackage{fourier-otf}
```

But `\setmainfont{Erewhon}` and `\setmathfont{Erewhon-Math}` also work. As of February 2020, I needed the following workaround before `fourier-otf` to enable bold text:

```
% Workaround for the definition of theorem headers:
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures[Erewhon]{FontFace = {bx}{n}{Erewhon-Bold.otf}}
```

[image: Erewhon Math Sample]

### KpMath

This is an OpenType version of `kpfonts` by Christophe Caignaert.

```
% LaTeX
\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}
```

[image: KpMath]

KpMath fonts provide 5 styles, and can be set via math versions:

```
\setmathfont{KpMath-Regular.otf}[version=regular]
\setmathfont{KpMath-Bold.otf}[version=bold]
\setmathfont{KpMath-Semibold.otf}[version=semibold]
\setmathfont{KpMath-Sans.otf}[version=sans]
\setmathfont{KpMath-Light.otf}[version=light]
```

[image: KpMath multiple]

The `\boldmath` and `\boldsymbol` commands switch to the `bold` math version, so most authors will want to pick one of these weights as the default and the other as bold, *e.g.*

```
\setmathfont{KPMath-Light.otf}
\setmathfont{KPMath-Semibold.otf}[
  version=bold]
```

might better match the weights of the text fonts.  This lets you format headers with `\bfseries\boldmath` to have the math match the text.

If you truly need to switch between three or more math styles in the same document, you can adapt the `\boldsymbol` code from `amsbsy.sty` to other math styles.

### New Computer Modern

A fork of Latin Modern that adds support for more script and math symbols, including Greek, Cyrillic, Hebrew, Cherokee and all the symbols in the STIX fonts.  It also comes in a slightly-heavier Book weight.  As of 2020, there are some features of Latin Modern it does not yet support, such as optical sizes and upright italics.

In book weight:

```
\usepackage[default]{fontsetup}
```

[image: New Computer Modern Book sample]

And in regular weight:

```
\usepackage[olddefault]{fontsetup}
```

[image: New Computer Modern Regular sample]

### Concrete Math

The `concmath-otf` package offers an Opentype version of the Concrete Math font created by Ulrik Vieth in MetaFont. `concmath-otf.sty` is a replacement for the original `concmath.sty` package.

```
% LaTeX
\usepackage{concmath-otf}
```

[image: concretemath]

### XCharter

XCharter-Math is an Opentype mathematical font based on Bitstream Charter meant to be used with XCharter text fonts.

```
% LaTeX
\usepackage{xcharter-otf}
```

[image: xchartermath]

### Lato Math

There exists a GitHub repository providing math support to Lato: https://github.com/abccsss/LatoMath. The font has not been uploaded to CTAN yet. Generated `.otf` file from GitHub: [LatoMath.otf](https://github.com/abccsss/LatoMath/releases/download/v0.1/LatoMath.otf)

[image]

### Euler-Math

An extension of the Neo Euler math font with a mostly complete symbol set. It is shown with both CMU Concrete and TeX Gyre Pagella (Palatino) as text fonts.

```
% LaTeX
\usepackage{euler-math}
\setmainfont{CMU Concrete}
```

[image: euler-math, concrete]

```
% LaTeX
\usepackage{euler-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
```

[image: euler-math, pagella]

### Neo Euler (Free but Incomplete)

A conversion by Khaled Hosny of the AMS Euler font designed by Hermann Zapf for the book DEK co-authored, *Concrete Mathematics: A Foundation for Computer Science*.

The code @davislor wrote below is now available in a package, although you will still need to [download `euler.otf` from its repository.](https://github.com/khaledhosny/euler-otf)  You can now write either

```
\usepackage[neoeuler]{fontsetup}
```

or

```
\usepackage{fspneoeulerot}
```

But here is the explanation of what they do:

AMS Euler was originally matched with the font Concrete Roman, which is now available from the Computer Modern Unicode project as CMU Concrete.  Euler goes well with Zapf’s other famous fonts, the serif font Palatino (and therefore its many clones, including Pagella and Asana) and the sans-serif font Optima (which has an OpenType clone, URW Classico).  Linux Libertine and its extension Libertinus are also good matches for it, and Libertinus Math, also by Khaled Hosny, shows some similarities.

Neo Euler was abandoned in 2010 and has a smaller repertoire of glyphs than the other fonts (nor will Zapf, who passed away in 2015, draw any more), so if it is missing any glyph you need, you might want to load it with the `range=` option, to use it with a fallback font that contains the glyphs it’s missing.  The following loads all glyphs defined in Neo Euler, loads CMU Concrete as the text font, and uses Libertinus Math as the fallback for the rest (such as the ratio).

Since Neo Euler has upright glyphs and no italic glyphs, it requires the `math-style=upright` option of `unicode-math`.  Unfortunately, the font metrics for subscripts and superscripts appear to be broken, so this example turns off script style for letters and numerals.  It also makes sure to load the Greek lowercase letters as upright.  If you want to use it with the full range of math alphabets, see below for a demo of how to fill in the missing pieces from other fonts.

```
% LaTeX
\unimathsetup{math-style=upright}
\setmainfont{CMU Concrete}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
\setmathfont[range={"0000-"0001,"0020-"007E,
                    "00A0,"00A7-"00A8,"00AC,"00AF,"00B1,"00B4-"00B5,"00B7,
                    "00D7,"00F7,
                    "0131,
                    "0237,"02C6-"02C7,"02D8-"02DA,"02DC,
                    "0300-"030C,"030F,"0311,"0323-"0325,"032E-"0332,"0338,
                    "0391-"0393,"0395-"03A1,"03A3-"03A8,"03B1-"03BB,
                    "03BD-"03C1,"03C3-"03C9,"03D1,"03D5-"03D6,"03F5,
                    "2016,"2018-"2019,"2021,"2026-"202C,"2032-"2037,"2044,
                    "2057,"20D6-"20D7,"20DB-"20DD,"20E1,"20EE-"20EF,
                    "210B-"210C,"210E-"2113,"2118,"211B-"211C,"2126-"2128,
                    "212C-"212D,"2130-"2131,"2133,"2135,"2190-"2199,
                    "21A4,"21A6,"21A9-"21AA,"21BC-"21CC,"21D0-"21D5,
                    "2200,"2202-"2209,"220B-"220C,"220F-"2213,"2215-"221E,
                    "2223,"2225,"2227-"222E,"2234-"2235,"2237-"223D,
                    "2240-"224C,"2260-"2269,"226E-"2279,"2282-"228B,"228E,
                    "2291-"2292,"2295-"2299,"22A2-"22A5,"22C0-"22C5,
                    "22DC-"22DD,"22EF,"22F0-"22F1,
                    "2308-"230B,"2320-"2321,"2329-"232A,"239B-"23AE,
                    "23DC-"23DF,
                    "27E8-"27E9,"27F5-"27FE,"2A0C,"2B1A,
                    "1D400-"1D433,"1D49C,"1D49E-"1D49F,"1D4A2,"1D4A5-"1D4A6,
                    "1D4A9-"1D4AC,"1D4AE-"1D4B5,"1D4D0-"1D4E9,"1D504-"1D505,
                    "1D507-"1D50A,"1D50D-"1D514,"1D516-"1D51C,"1D51E-"1D537,
                    "1D56C-"1D59F,"1D6A8-"1D6B8,"1D6BA-"1D6D2,"1D6D4-"1D6DD,
                    "1D6DF,"1D6E1,"1D7CE-"1D7D7
                   }]{Neo Euler}
\setmathfont[range=up/{greek,Greek}, script-features={}, sscript-features={}
            ]{Neo Euler}
\setmathfont[range=up/{latin,Latin,num}, script-features={}, sscript-features={}
            ]{Neo Euler}
```

[image: Neo Euler with CMU Concrete]

Another popular set-up is to use the upright letters from Neo Euler in combination with Palatino.

```
\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Palatino Linotype}[ % Or TeX Gyre Pagella, etc.
  Scale=1.0,
  Ligatures={Common,Rare,TeX}] 
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}[
  Scale=MatchLowercase]
\setmathfont{euler.otf}[
  range={up/{Latin,latin,Greek,Greek},
         bfup/{Latin,latin,Greek,Greek},
         cal, bfcal, frak, bffrak},
  Scale=MatchLowercase,
  script-features={},
  sscript-features={}]
```

[image: Neo Euler and TeX Gyre Pagella Math]

### STIX Math Regular

One of the first attempts to create a comprehensive set of all scientific, technical and mathematical symbols.  STIX was based on Elsevier’s Esstix, and inspired by Monotype’s Times 4-Line Mathematics Series 569, a font from the middle of the century that simplified typesetting mathematics on mechanical printing presses. The OpenType math support is not complete, which led to the XITS Math project being created.

```
% LaTeX
\setmainfont{STIX}
\setmathfont{STIX Math}
% ConTeXt
\setupbodyfont[stix]
```

[image: STIX Math Regular]

### Noto Sans Math (Incomplete)

As of June 2020, this font is available from [the Noto fonts GitHub page.](https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-fonts/tree/master/hinted/NotoSansMath)  It does not yet fully implement OpenType math features, so you will get a warning if you use it as your primary math font.

```
\setmainfont{Noto Sans}
\setmathfont{Noto Sans Math}
```

[image: Noto Sans Math Sample]

### Berenis ADF Pro (Incomplete)

This is an incomplete font not included with TeX Live.  It is available *gratis* [from the foundry](http://arkandis.tuxfamily.org/adffonts.html).  The text font also contains rare ligatures not shown here, as they look out of place in a mathematical text.

Whether this should be considered an “OpenType math font” is debatable. It lacks an OpenType math table, and `unicode-math` 0.81 will not consider it valid as the main math font. This sample falls back to Latin Modern Math as the default math font, then loads every glyph this font defines over that, which you can do for any TrueType or OpenType font.  It contains only upright symbols, so it will only work with the `math-style=upright` option of `unicode-math` (or if you kitbash it to import symbols from the text fonts; see below).

Despite being licensed under the GPL2, it does not come with any source files.

```
% LaTeX
\unimathsetup{math-style=upright}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={Common,TeX}]{Berenis ADF Pro}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range={"0020-"007E,"00A0-"021F,"0237,"0259,"02C6,"02C7,
  "02D8-"02DD,"0311,"0326,"037B-"037E,"0384-"038A,"038C-"045F,"0490-"0491,
  "1E10-"1E11,"1E80-"1E85,"1EF2-"1EF3,"2000-"2026,"2030,"2039-"203A,"2044,
  "2070,"2074-"207A,"207D-"208A,"208D-"208E,"20AC,"20DD-"20DF,"2102-"2103,
  "2109,"210E-"210F,"2113,"2116,"2122,"2126,"212A,"212C-"212E,"2133,"213D,
  "2153-"215E,"2190-"219D,"21A4-"21A8,"21AE-"21CA,"21D1-"21EA,"2202-"2212,
  "2216-"221E,"2223-"222D,"223C="223D,"2241,"2248-"2249,"224D,"2260,
  "2264-"2265,"226A-"226B,"226D-"2275,"227A-"227B,"2280-"2281,"2290-"2294,
  "22C4-"22C5,"22E2-"22E3,"22EF,"2302-"2303,"25CA,"FB00-"FB06}
             ]{Berenis ADF Pro Math Regular}
```

[image: Berenis ADF Pro]

## Commercial Fonts

### Lucida (Commercial)

Distributed by the TeX User Group.  https://tug.org/store/lucida/index.html

```
% LaTeX
\setmainfont[
  UprightFont = *,
  ItalicFont = *-Italic,
  BoldFont = *-Demi,
  BoldItalicFont = *-DemiItalic,
  Extension = .otf
]{LucidaBrightOT}
\setmathfont{LucidaBrightMathOT}
\setmathfont[version=bold]{LucidaBrightMathOT-Demi}
% ConTeXt
\setupbodyfont[lucidaot]
```

[image: Lucida]

### Minion Math (Commercial)

[Distributed by its designer,](http://typoma.de/en/fonts.html) Johannes Küster.  It comes in four weights and five optical sizes, the most of any OpenType math font (as of 2019).

```
% LaTeX
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
 
\setmathfont[
SizeFeatures = {
  {Size = -6, Font = MinionMath-Tiny, Style = MathScriptScript},
  {Size = 6-8.4, Font = MinionMath-Capt, Style = MathScript},
  {Size = 8.4-13, Font = MinionMath-Regular},
}]{MinionMath-Regular}
\setmathfont{MinionMath-Bold}[range={bfup->up,bfit->it}]
% ConTeXt
\setupbodyfont[minion]
```

[image: Minion Math]

### Cambria Math (Commercial)

This is the font Microsoft Office uses for its equations.  The font ships with Microsoft Windows Vista and later, with MS Office, and an early version was bundled with some versions of the MS Office viewers.  Monotype sells licenses to use it on workstations and embed it in webpages, but the most likely way to have a legal copy of it on Linux is with a symbolic link in `/usr/local/share/fonts/` or `~/.fonts` to `cambria_01.ttf` on a Windows partition.

```
% LaTeX
\setmainfont{Cambria}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}
% ConTeXt
\setupbodyfont[cambria]
```

[image: Cambria]

## Stylistic Sets and Alternates

Many of these fonts contain either stylistic sets or stylistic alternates that allow you to select between different versions of some of the symbols in the font.  STIX Two has an especially large number, [and actually documents them](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/stix2-otf/STIX_2.0.0_stylistic_sets.pdf).  If a font doesn’t, you can still check what it currently supports by opening it in FontForge.  This is in addition to the choices you can make with package options.

For example, both XITS and STIX Two include a Stylistic Set 8 with alternative upright integrals.  (In fact, STIX Two supports every stylistic set XITS Math does.)  You can select them as follows:

```
% LaTeX
\setmainfont{XITS}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmathfont[range={"222B-"2233,"2A0B-"2A1C},StylisticSet=8]{XITS Math}
```

[image: XITS with upright integrals]

For comparison, here is the vanilla XITS example again:

[image: XITS]

A common use of these alternative styles is on the script alphabet.  Traditionally, LaTeX had separate alphabets for `\mathcal` and `\mathscr`.  However, the Unicode consortium decided that no mathematical texts use both of these with different meanings, so they were different presentation forms assigned to the same codepoints.

However, `unicode-math` allows you to load different alphabets as `\mathcal` and `\mathscr`, and also `\mathbfcal` and `\mathbfscr`.  Some fonts, such as XITS, implement this as a stylistic set, some, such as Asana Math, implement it as a stylistic alternative, and others require you to load a different font of you want to do that.  For example, to do it with Asana Math:

```
% LaTeX
\documentclass[preview,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont[Ligatures={Common,Rare,TeX}]{Palatino Linotype}
% You might have Palatino or Palatino Linotype installed.
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}

\setmathfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Asana Math}
\setmathfont[range={cal,bfcal},
             Alternate,
             Scale=MatchUppercase]
            {Asana Math}

\begin{document}
Calligraphic: \(\mathcal{ABC}\) \qquad Script: \(\mathscr{ABC}\)
\end{document}
```

[image: Asana Math script alphabets]

## Kitbashing Math Fonts

It is possible to load symbols from any font into a math style, and use them as symbols with `\symup`.  For example, nearly all fonts include a *QED* symbol at U+220E, but what it looks like varies considerably.  To get the version in XITS Math (the black tombstone that matches the 1997 edition of *The Art of Computer Programming*), you can use the commands:

```
% LaTeX
\documentclass[preview,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont[range=`∎]{XITS Math}
\DeclareRobustCommand\qedsymbol{\ensuremath{\symup{∎}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}[Tautology]
True
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image: Tautology with QED]

Another common request is to combine the letters of a text font family with the symbols of a math font.  Since Neo Euler is the math font lacking italic letters at all, it makes a good example.  A frequent recommendation is to combine Euler with Hermann Zapf’s other creation, Palatino.  Since both Pagella and Asana are clones of Palatino, we can use Pagella as the text fonts and take all the missing glyphs, including italic math letters, from Asana.

This gives us the repertoire to convert the sample to ISO style (a great excuse to show off upright and italic math letters together).  Constants such as π and i remain upright (written `2 \symup{\pi i}`, the denominator still shows Euler math letters). Uppercase Greek letters, such as the Gamma function, are now italic rather than upright, but symbols based on Greek letters, such as summation and product, remain the same.

Essentially, this adds a few lines to the bottom of the preamble filling in all the remaining math alphabets and setting up digits to match the text font.

```
% LaTeX
\unimathsetup{math-style=ISO, partial=upright, nabla=upright}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\setmathfont[range={"0000-"0001,"0020-"007E,
                    "00A0,"00A7-"00A8,"00AC,"00AF,"00B1,"00B4-"00B5,"00B7,
                    "00D7,"00F7,
                    "0131,
                    "0237,"02C6-"02C7,"02D8-"02DA,"02DC,
                    "0300-"030C,"030F,"0311,"0323-"0325,"032E-"0332,"0338,
                    "0391-"0393,"0395-"03A1,"03A3-"03A8,"03B1-"03BB,
                    "03BD-"03C1,"03C3-"03C9,"03D1,"03D5-"03D6,"03F5,
                    "2016,"2018-"2019,"2021,"2026-"202C,"2032-"2037,"2044,
                    "2057,"20D6-"20D7,"20DB-"20DD,"20E1,"20EE-"20EF,
                    "210B-"210C,"210E-"2113,"2118,"211B-"211C,"2126-"2128,
                    "212C-"212D,"2130-"2131,"2133,"2135,"2190-"2199,
                    "21A4,"21A6,"21A9-"21AA,"21BC-"21CC,"21D0-"21D5,
                    "2200,"2202-"2209,"220B-"220C,"220F-"2213,"2215-"221E,
                    "2223,"2225,"2227-"222E,"2234-"2235,"2237-"223D,
                    "2240-"224C,"2260-"2269,"226E-"2279,"2282-"228B,"228E,
                    "2291-"2292,"2295-"2299,"22A2-"22A5,"22C0-"22C5,
                    "22DC-"22DD,"22EF,"22F0-"22F1,
                    "2308-"230B,"2320-"2321,"2329-"232A,"239B-"23AE,
                    "23DC-"23DF,
                    "27E8-"27E9,"27F5-"27FE,"2A0C,"2B1A,
                    "1D400-"1D433,"1D49C,"1D49E-"1D49F,"1D4A2,"1D4A5-"1D4A6,
                    "1D4A9-"1D4AC,"1D4AE-"1D4B5,"1D4D0-"1D4E9,"1D504-"1D505,
                    "1D507-"1D50A,"1D50D-"1D514,"1D516-"1D51C,"1D51E-"1D537,
                    "1D56C-"1D59F,"1D6A8-"1D6B8,"1D6BA-"1D6D2,"1D6D4-"1D6DD,
                    "1D6DF,"1D6E1,"1D7CE-"1D7D7
                   }]{Neo Euler}
\setmathfont[range=up/{greek,Greek}, script-features={}, sscript-features={}
            ]{Neo Euler}
\setmathfont[range=up/{latin,Latin}, script-features={}, sscript-features={}
            ]{Neo Euler}
\setmathfont[range={bfup/{latin, Latin, greek, Greek}, frak, bffrak, cal},
             script-features={}, sscript-features={}
            ]{Neo Euler}
\setmathfont[range={up/num, bfup/num, it, bfit, scr, bfscr,
                    sfup, sfit, bfsfup, bfsfit, tt}
            ]{Asana Math}
\setmathfont[range=bfcal, Scale=MatchUppercase, Alternate]{Asana Math}
\setmathfont[range=bb, Scale=MatchUppercase]{Latin Modern Math}
```

[image: Neo Euler plus Asana plus Latin Modern with Pagella]

Here again is the example with Neo Euler as the math font:

[image: Neo Euler with CMU Concrete]

(The eagle-eyed will have noticed one more unexplained line of code, which sets the `partial` and `nabla` package options to `upright`.  Neo Euler contains the upright ∂ symbol in U+2202, but not the cursive ∂ symbol at U+1D715, which confuses `unicode-math`.  Otherwise, load U+1D715 from another math font.)

It is often a good idea to set up subscripts, superscripts, sub-subscripts and super-superscripts to use a smaller *optical size*, to make it more legible at smaller sizes.  There are three methods.  There might be a companion font designed for smaller sizes. which you would load with `script-font=`.  (The commercial font Aldus is intended as this for Palatino.)  Many fonts, including Latin Modern and all the TeX Gyre fonts, come with different optical sizes and you can select a smaller one, *e.g.* `script-features={OpticalSize=8}, sscript-features={OpticalSize=6}`.  Finally, math fonts support the font features `script-features={Script=Math, Style=MathScript}, sscript-features={Script=Math, Style=MathScriptScript}`.

For more information, see the documentation of the [`unicode-math`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unicode-math.pdf) and [`fontspec`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/fontspec.pdf) packages.

Comment: As rationale for not using the default math fonts is often to get better match with text fonts, it would be interesting to mention which scripts are supported by the matching text fonts. For example as a far as I know the TeX Gyre only support the Latin script, which is a serious limitation for use in automated document production where Unicode characters may pop up from Cyrillic, Greek, Hebrew, CJK, ...

Comment: @jfbu This answer is CW with exactly that intention.  Please add your improvements.

Comment: I don't know enough about fonts and don't have access to the commercial fonts so I hope the information will be added by someone else.

Comment: There’s also [Berenis ADF Pro Math](http://arkandis.tuxfamily.org/adffonts.html). However, `fontspec` complains that `OpenType feature Style=MathScript (ssty) not available for font BerenisADFProMath with script Math and language Default` and the PDF output uses Berenis only for the text fonts, substituting Latin Modern for the math. Someone who knows about making math fonts may want to look into fixing this one (and whether it’s worth fixing).

Comment: @Davislor Please add all of this information to the community wiki answer.

Comment: @Davislor indeed this is complex... I am sure people will find it useful (silencing here any opinion I might have about Euler like fonts). I noticed there is no mention of [mathspec](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathspec) here. Not to suggest extra edits, as the answer looks big and perhaps drifted a bit from original focus.

Comment: I think there used to be instructions for how to convert the PDFs to PNGs the correct width. What I finally came up with was: `convert -density 120 -background white -compose src-in -alpha Remove -trim +repage -gravity center -extent 636 -frame 2 residue-template.pdf residue-template.png`.  The `-density` argument will vary by the metrics of the font so as to get take up the correct amount of horizontal space, and should be between 120 and 130.  If you want a lowest common denominator, use 120.

Comment: @Davislor I used to use `-alpha Remove` myself as well but apparently that [turns off anti-aliasing for fonts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/228881).  That is why I switched to `mutool`.

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks! Checked the link. ImageMagick 7 appears to fix that bug from 3 years ago, and the output is definitely anti-aliased. It does still set the output to grayscale. The trick from the accepted answer at your link, to specify the output as `png24:residue-template.png`, still works. However, since the R,G and B values of every shade of gray are still equal, there are only 256 shades of gray being used. At a glance, all the workaround appears to do is increase the file sizes by 50%.

Comment: You might also need to use `magick convert` rather than `convert`. On further testing, ImageMagick 7 will determine the minimum color depth needed for the image, so I sometimes see it give me a monochrome bit depth of 4.

Comment: @jfbu I asked a question about this a long time ago [What is the difference between unicode-math and mathspec?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118244)  It could maybe be linked.  Other than that I agree, that this is going beyond the scope.

Comment: @HenriMenke Is there a better place to put the examples of kitbashing and multilingual text? I don’t believe there’s a template to correctly use Neo Euler anywhere else.

Comment: @HenriMenke partially off-topic (and possibly to be removed comment): my `mathastext` provides since 2013 a macro `\MTsetmathskips` to fix glyph collisions with letters such as `f` coming from text fonts and used in math mode. With it results of using traditional TeX-prepared fonts in math can be made to look definitily better than the samples here with the TeX Gyre Math fonts such as Bonum, Pagella, Schola and Termes (see the `|f(z)|` e.g.). I wonder if some more Unicode native package should provide that. I recall `\XeTeXintercharclass` is off in math mode, sadly. Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: The kerning in the Asana-Palatino example looks terrible. What has happened there? In particular the words `some` and `operators`.

Comment: @JohnDorian Good catch. Bug in ImageMagick’s conversion of PDF to PNG with the letter o in Palatino Linotype. (Issue with hinting?) Henri Menke’s `mutool` solution might work better, but as a quick  workaround, I substituted Pagella.

Comment: @HenriMenke Short answer: `unicode-math` allows you to use OpenType math fonts, and `mathspec` lets you use letters and numerals from an OpenType font along with a legacy math font. They cannot be combined.  Since this question is about OpenType math fonts, all answers will use `unicode-math` and not `mathspec`, and use `\setmathfont` rather than `\setmathsfont`. (You know this, but I thought it worth leaving a comment about.)

Comment: STIX2 is finally in CTAN: https://ctan.org/pkg/stix2-otf

Comment: Added XITS Math Bold and STIX Math Regular.

Comment: Cambria kerning is also odd. Look at »region« and »closed« (and some more).

Comment: @JohnDorian I would actually attribute this to a rendering artifact.  Cambria is one of the better math fonts.

Comment: Some fonts have what look like errors: for example, using Libertinus, in the first theorem, "f(" appears with the "f" touching the "(". Is this caused by a bug in the font? Is there a way a non-knowledgeable user like myself can attempt to fix such problems?

Comment: @MBaz There’s a good chance that those are artifacts of the image tools we used and that running the same example yourself won’t reproduce them. Otherwise, technically yes, but bug the maintainer of the font about it. Several are works in progress.

Comment: Garamond math is now on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/garamond-math) as of Jan 28, 2019

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks for the ConTeXt examples! I suspect there was an error with the one for Asana Math, though.

Comment: @Krishna Thanks! Updated the information for both Fira and Garamond Math.

Comment: Is it just me or do some pictures look blurred while others sharp? Would it make sense to recreate all picture with the same (preferably high) rendering settings to convert to PNG?

Comment: fyi, Fira Math no longer works on TexLive 2020. I get error `Package fontspec Error: The font "FiraGO" cannot be found.`. Compiled using your specs with lualatex.
`\usepackage[mathit=sym,bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{FiraGO}
\setmathfont{FiraMath-Regular}`

Comment: @Nasser The description might be a bit misleading. Not all fonts presented here are part of TeX Live.

Comment: A new package [concmath-otf](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/concmath-otf) – Concrete based OpenType Math has appeared. I've added that to the answer. Please rectify if any changes are needed. Also, New Computer Modern now has 8pt size glyphs as well.

Comment: CMU Concrete italic text isn't properly spaced. I don't know how to correct it.

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis This looks like it's using math italics for text. Maybe your TeX installation is broken. I've updated the screenshot.

Answer (score 4):

Two new fonts have recently appeared, NagwaTK and Old Standard Math.

NagwaTK:

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{NagwaTKText}
\setmathfont{NagwaTKMath-Regular.otf}
```

[image: nagwatk]

Old Standard Math:

```
\usepackage[oldstandard]{fontsetup}
```

[image: old standard]

Erewhon Math (`fourier-otf`), XCharter Math (`xcharter-otf`) and Concete Math (`concmath-otf`) offer limited bold math variants, which are loaded automatically by invoking the appropriate package, e.g. `\usepackage{concmath-otf}` to load the Concrete text, math and bold math fonts. The bold math fonts can be loaded manually as well using `\setmathfont{Concrete-Math-Bold.otf}[version=bold]` or `\setmathfont{Concrete-Math-Regular.otf}[BoldFont=Concrete-Math-Bold.otf]`.

One can adjust the adjust the `DisplayOperatorMinHeight` font parameter using `\everydisplay{\Umathoperatorsize\displaystyle=4ex}` as explained in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/489878/128462), to get longer integrals for TeX Gyre fonts.
[image: tex gyre]

Comment: I have added this as a new answer since addition of this answer to the existing one would exceed the character limit.