# open type math font STIX letters are very close to each others in some places

Tags: fonts, stix

I was trying some fonts from this post [which-opentype-math-fonts-are-available](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425098/which-opentype-math-fonts-are-available)

I downloaded and installed STIX two

[image: Mathematica graphics]

From http://stixfonts.org/ and have been using it for few days. It looks really nice. Except sometimes some of math letters in fractions hit each others.

Compare this image (will show MWE below), comparing STIX and STIX two and the default  latex font. Notice how the denominator is touching the math in the line below it

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

%\setmainfont{XITS}
%\setmathfont{XITS Math}        
\begin{document}

\[
 G(x,s)  = \left\{
    \begin{array}[c]{ccc}%
       \frac{\cos s}{\cos(1)  }\sin(1-x)   &  & 0\leq s\leq x\\
       \frac{\cos x}{\cos(1)  }\sin(1-s)   &  & x\leq s\leq 1
     \end{array}
          \right.
\]

\end{document}
```

Compiled using `lualatex foo.tex`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This below is the default Latex font:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The question is, is there is something one can do to fix this? Is this a bug in the font? I find it harder to read when the letters are touching each others. Otherwise, it is a nice font. I think they put too much space between the fraction line and the denominator. With the default font, the spacing is much better.

To install the fonts, I unzipped the file from the above link, and copied the 3 font folders to `~./fonts` folder. That is all. This is on cygwin. On windows or mac, the fonts need to be moved to wherever the opentype fonts folder is.

Comment: it doesn't look great the parameters can be tweeked a bit but (as has been said multiple times before) `\left(  1-x\right) ` is bad input and would be better as `(1-x)`

Comment: to +1 @DavidCarlisle: the spacing between G and opening parenthesis looks very bad in both tests due to bad `\left(x, s\right)` input...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I removed the `\left(` and `\right)` but the output still looks the same.

Comment: as a workaround you could increase baselineskip or arraystretch when using stix 2

Comment: I'd be more worried about the distance of numerator and denominator from the fraction line, which I find excessive with STIX Two Math.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default spacing is rather cramped

[image]

You could open up arrays when using stix 2 by adding

```
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
```

to the preamble

[image]

Although really `array` is not suitable for this kind of layout, it uses inline math not display and is designed for setting arrays and matrices, if you put `\arraystretch` back to the default and use cases then you get

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}

%\setmainfont{XITS}
%\setmathfont{XITS Math}        
\begin{document}

\[
 G(x,s)  = 
    \begin{cases}
       \frac{\cos s}{\cos(1)  }\sin(1-x)   &   0\leq s\leq x\\
       \frac{\cos x}{\cos(1)  }\sin(1-s)   & x\leq s\leq 1
     \end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

Or perhaps with stix2 you should increase baselinestretch slightly, adding

```
\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.1}
```

gives

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.1}

%\setmainfont{XITS}
%\setmathfont{XITS Math}        
\begin{document}

\[
 G(x,s)  = 
    \begin{cases}
       \frac{\cos s}{\cos(1)  }\sin(1-x)   &   0\leq s\leq x\\
       \frac{\cos x}{\cos(1)  }\sin(1-s)   & x\leq s\leq 1
     \end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```