# How to make an epsilon with ebgaramond-maths

Tags: fonts, greek, ebgaramond

I am using ebgaramond font and trying to make an epsilon:

```
\documentclass[10pt,article]{memoir}

\usepackage[lining]{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}

\begin{document}
Epilon: $\epsilon$

\end{document}
```

But it won't show up:  (never mind the spelling the command is right:)

[image]

Does the font lack it and there is no automatic fall-back or what is going on here? What can I do to get around it?

Comment: I just found `\varepsilon` as a quick and hacky fix but it can't be the right way now can it....

Comment: @moewe hm I really thought it would fall back to some other version of the symbol then... I guess I am just plain wrong on that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may want to contact the package's author (email is available on the front page of the package's user guide) and ask if the missing `\epsilon` glyph is a bug. While you're at it, you may also wanto to ask about `\theta` (which looks a lot like `\vartheta`), `\xi` (its scaling may be off), `\varpi` (too much whitespace to the right of the glyph?), and `\rho` (which looks rather like `\varrho`).

[image]

Just for comparison, here are the same glyphs from Computer Modern.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,article]{memoir}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths} % comment out to get Computer Modern
\begin{document}

$\alpha\beta\gamma\delta[\epsilon]\varepsilon\zeta
\eta\theta\vartheta\iota\kappa\lambda\mu\nu
\xi\pi\varpi\rho\varrho\sigma\varsigma\tau
\upsilon\phi\varphi\chi\psi\omega$ % \omicron not defined

\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't post a listing of uppercase Greek characters since they look just fine.

Comment: The documentation of the package says that characters are missing (it doesn't say which one, but it is not only epsilon as one can check with a fonttable. ).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer referring to package documentation: a low blow!

Answer (score 6):

The log reports

```
Missing character: There is no ^^O in font EBGaramond12-Italic--oml-ebgaramond!
```

which seems like an error in the font setup.

`\varepsilon` works though

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,article]{memoir}

\usepackage[lining]{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}

\begin{document}
Epsilon: $[\epsilon][\varepsilon]$

\end{document}
```

Comment: If no suitable Greek is freely available the package probably ought to make the commands give an error rather than just access missing glyphs

Answer (score 4):

There is now a [Garamond Math](https://github.com/YuanshengZhao/Garamond-Math) OpenType font matching EB Garamond, usable with `unicode-math`.  I also added it to [the OpenType Math Fonts community answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425098/which-opentype-math-fonts-are-available/425099#425099).

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\setmathfont{Garamond Math}[Scale=MatchUppercase]

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
   &\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = L \iff \\
   &\quad \forall \epsilon > 0. \exists \delta > 0. \forall x \in D. \\
   &\quad\left\lvert x-c \right\rvert < \delta \implies
         \left\lvert f(x) - L \right\rvert < \epsilon
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Garamond Math Sample]

Note that, as of June 2018, [the full EB Garamond 12 font family](https://github.com/octaviopardo/EBGaramond12/) is not yet in TeX Live, only the Regular and Italic faces.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get a fallback while experimenting with different fonts, you can substitute `\epsilon` with `\varepsilon` when the former is not available:

```
\documentclass[10pt,article]{memoir}

\usepackage[lining]{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}

\begingroup
\def\extract#1"#2#3#4\extract{
  \gdef\epsilon{%
    \iffontchar\textfont "#2 "#3#4
      \mathchar"#2#3#4
    \else
      \varepsilon
    \fi
  }%
}
\expandafter\extract\meaning\epsilon\extract
\endgroup

\begin{document}

epsilon: $\epsilon$

varepsilon: $\varepsilon$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If I comment out the two `\usepackage` lines, I get

[image]

If you finally decide for `ebgaramond-maths`, then just add

```
\renewcommand{\epsilon}{\varepsilon}
```

instead of the code between `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` (inclusive).

Answer (score 0):

You can also load the newtxmath package and use `\epsilonup` as replacement for `\epsilon`. `\epsilonup` looks more similar to the `\epsilon` used by the most other math fonts.

```
\documentclass[10pt,article]{memoir}

\usepackage[lining]{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}

\begin{document}
Epsilon: $\varepsilon$ \\
Epsilon: $\epsilonup$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure this is a viable solution, because `newtxmath` does several redeclarations of symbols, whereas `ebgaramond-maths` relies on standard math codes. For instance, uppercase Greek letters will be from `newtxmath` rather than `ebgaramond-maths`.

Comment: I wasn't aware of these drawbacks, so the solution has to be taken with care.
I did some testing with `newtxmath` and this raised a few additional questions to me. I run the above example with and w/o newtxmath for uppercase Greek letters and the result differs for pdflatex, xelatex, and lualatex. But I think this shouldn't be discussed in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[10pt,article]{memoir}

\usepackage[lf,ebgaramond]{newtx}


\begin{document}
Epsilon: $\epsilon$

\end{document}
```

[image: ebgaramond epsilon via newtx]