# Neo Euler does not work with some symbols

Tags: fonts, xetex, unicode-math, euler

I was trying to prepare some slides in `XeLaTeX` with main font `Candara` and Math font `Neo Euler`, but some symbols, like `\angle`, doesn't work. I am appending a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=Lining]{Candara}
\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Neo Euler}
\usepackage[mode=math]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\[
\angle ABC \ang{36}
\]

\end{document}
```

Can you please help me: I do need those symbols.

Thank you.

Comment: FYI, according to the [Neo Euler GitHub page](https://github.com/khaledhosny/euler-otf), the font project was abandoned.

Comment: What would you suggest me to use, then? Come back to the classic `euler`package? I tried, but still have problems with `siunitx` because `\ang` still doesn't work

Comment: You can get the angle from another font: `\setmathfont[range={"2220}]{Latin Modern Math}`. And the degree should be possible too, but I don't have time now to look up where siunitx get it from.

Comment: That would be a huge patchwork of fonts, though. I would prefer to use the same font. However, I have adjusted `siunitx` to work with `euler` and the result is fairly good, so far

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neo Euler is an incomplete font which is no longer being maintained.  (Sadly, its creator, Hermann Zapf, is no longer with us and cannot draw any new symbols for it.)

The best way to use it is to load a more comprehensive math font as the fallback, then load only the symbols present in Neo Euler over it with the `range=` option.  You can find [a demonstration here.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425098/which-opentype-math-fonts-are-available)  Remember to load `unicode-math` with the `math-style=upright` option, and you might want to make `\symup` and `\symbfup` the defaults for `\mathup` and `\mathbf`.