# How to make mtpro2 math font a litte bit more thick？

Tags: fonts, fontsize, mtpro, math-fonts

I want to use mtpro2 together with [Souce Serif Pro](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Source+Serif+Pro), but default mtpro2 looks like too thin.
[image]
[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lite,subscriptcorrection,slantedGreek,nofontinfo]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Source Serif Pro}  


\begin{document}
    Source Serif Pro $f=|a|/3$ with mtpro2

    %Source Serif Pro $f=|a|/3$ with XITS Math

\end{document}
```

How to make it heavier? 
Thanke you all in advance

Comment: If you don't need to use `mtpro2` specifically, XITS Math matches XITS and comes in a bold weight.

Answer (score 2):

See section 2.5 of [the package documentation](https://www.pctex.com/files/managed/1/1b/mtpro2Abbrev.pdf) for the use of the bold math and heavy math weights.

If neither of those is right for you, [you will need to pick another font.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425098/which-opentype-math-fonts-are-available). The `fontspec` package does, incidentally, have an option to make a font heavier, and `unicode-math` inherits it.