# A Whole List of Math Fonts for Greek Letters in LaTeX?

Tags: greek

Different people like different styles, and so it maybe useful to list all the math fonts for greek letters in latex. So far as I know, there are some math fonts for greek letters as follows for which the way to invoke see: http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-1/hartke/hartke.pdf.

1. Package: `Computer Modern`; Greek: `cm`

[image]

2. Package: `cmbright`; Greek: `cmbright`

[image]

3. Package: `ccfonts,eulervm`; Greek: `concrete` upshape

[image]

4. Package: `concmath`; Greek: `concrete` itshape

[image]

5. Package: `iwona`; Greek: `iwona`

[image]

6. Package: `kurier`; Greek: `kurier`

[image]

7. Package: `anttor`; Greek: `anttor`

[image]

8. Package: `kmath,kerkis`; Greek: `kerkis`

[image]

9. Package: `millennial,fouriernc`; Greek: `nc schlbk`

[image]

10. Package: `pxfonts,mathpazo,mathpple,newpxmath`; Greek: `palatino`

[image]

11. Package: `txfonts,mathtime (Belleek),mathptmx,newtxmath`; Greek: `times`

[image]

12. Package: `mbtimes`; Greek: `omega`

[image]

13. Package: `arev`; Greek: `arev`

[image]

14. Package: `mathdesign (Charter)`; Greek: `charter`

[image]

15. Package: `mathdesign (Garamond)`; Greek: `garamond`

[image]

16. Package: `mathdesign (Utopia)`; Greek: `utopia`

[image]

17. Package: `fourier`; Greek: `utopia`

[image]

Although there are many math fonts for greek letters, I didn't get what I like. So my question is

> **Are there some more choices?**

Comment: Aside from being opinion based, I would note that, with rare exception, you should use a complete font set (as designed), rather than to pick and choose individual characters from various fonts.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes So I intend to select a best font from the answers.

Comment: See http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/math.html

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes The fonts in your link are all in the list already.

Comment: You have done a lot of work. Might you consider putting something like this on CTAN for general distribution? You might, though, find that someone (I can't remember who) has beaten you to it.

Comment: Have you seen Scott Pakin's *The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbols List* (`> texdoc comprehensive`) ?

Comment: @PeterWilson I have seen that.

Comment: It is a stupid question. I would like to use the number 12 in your list (because of its nice \varphi ), but I do not succeed. I can not even download anything for the pacakage mbtimes (I do use TEX studio, and it ask me for the file mbtimes.cls). I have problem to find the font either.

Comment: I would add gfsartemisia and many more from Antonis Tsolomitis work available on CTAN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

- Any font from [The LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/mathfonts.html) that has math support
- Any [LGR-encoded Greek font](https://www.ctan.org/topic/font-greek), with `mathastext`
- Any [OML-encoded math font,](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/isomath/isomath.html) with `isomath`.
- Any [OpenType math font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425098/which-opentype-math-fonts-are-available) with `unicode-math`
- Any OpenType or TrueType font family with Greek letters at the right Unicode code points, using either the `range=` option of `\setmathfont` in `unicode-math` or the `\setmathsfont` command of `mathspec`
- Various legacy math packages with their own 8-bit encodings
- Any other font format, if you’re willing to convert it and do a lot of work on font metrics

My recommendation would be to use modern font formats and Unicode when you can, and legacy encodings when you have to.

Comment: @Mogic I don’t understand what you’re looking for.