# How to produce this Letter Phi

Tags: symbols

I am looking for a command to produce the letter $ \phi $ in such a beautiful, old style as the picture attached below.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which TeX program -- pdfTeX, XeTeX, LuaTeX, or maybe something else? -- you employ to compile your LaTeX document.

Comment: Thank you. I am using pdfTex.

Comment: Isn't  `\varphi` what you want?

Comment: Found ```\varphi``` too using http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: or `\upvarphi` from `upgreek`? You could easily find any symbol using http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: @Bernard No. it is not \varphi ! I am looking for a command (say, for example \mathscr) to produce this style, not a usual \phi or \varphi.

Comment: @EladDen It is really similar to \upvarphi, but I think they are not the same.

Comment: There's also `\textphi` from `textgreek`. basically I think you need a specific greek font that would look like this...

Comment: check this out https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/487710/a-whole-list-of-math-fonts-for-greek-letters-in-latex

Comment: it is a varphi, so the only question is what font is being used. Where did you get the picture you show? If you have that as pdf you can check exactly which fonts it is using using pdffonts utility or the font menu of your viewer.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69908/197451

Comment: What is the source of the image?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  it is taken from this paper DOI: 10.2307/2006966 I were not good to find font from the pdf file!

Comment: @Sebastiano I mentioned the paper which is the source of the image. Another paper which used this font, and is available for free is 10.1007/BF02392215, for example in the page 146

Comment: the pdf isn't generally available I think but if you have it, simply run the pdffonts command on it or use acrobat reader font menu and get a list of all the fonts in the document.

Comment: Correction, I got the file from jstor, but there are no digital fonts there it is just a scan of a paper copy of the Annals of Mathematics. so not useful for getting the fonts, also the exact same font may not be available digitally.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks a lot for your time and concern.