# Problem adding package mbtimes

Tags: fonts, packages, greek

This a question of a beginner. I would like to have old-fashioned Greek letter $ \varphi $. For instance, as the number 12 in the list in the question [A whole list of math fonts for greek letters in latex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/487710/a-whole-list-of-math-fonts-for-greek-letters-in-latex) 
The problem is that this font requires package mbtimes; I do use TEXStudio as compiler on a windows 8.1 system. The program was not able to run the package by itself (it asked for .cls file); But, I do not succeed in downloading package anywhere (There is one ftp page that does not response). 
I want to know what I should do to overcome the problem (I just want to have \varphi with this font; a single character would be enough for me).
By old-fashioned \varphi, I mean this one which I take from a paper (page 174 of the paper, 174 on the pdf file) which is freely available at https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.acta/1485889737
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The particular package you’re looking for was uploaded to a FTP site by the author, [nearly twenty years ago.](https://email.esm.psu.edu/pipermail/macosx-tex/2002-March/002212.html)  It’s neither in CTAN nor the Internet Archive, but maybe someone still has a copy.

Fonts that have a similar shape for `\varphi` include `stix`, `stix2` and `newpxmath`, or `unicode-math` with XITS Math, STIX Two Math or TeX Gyre Pagella Math.

If you find an OpenType or TrueType Greek font with the shape you like, you can use its Greek letters in `unicode-math` with *e.g.*

```
\setmathfont{GFS Didot Italic}[
   range=it/{Greek,greek},
   Scale=MatchLowercase]
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Your answer helped a lot. Finally I used TX Fonts, which its command \upvarphi produces a \varphi that is almost exactly the as \varphi in the mbtimes package.

Comment: This the command I used to add this \upvarphi to my text. 
\DeclareSymbolFont{lettersA}{U}{txmia}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{lettersA}{bold}{U}{txmia}{bx}{it}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{txmia}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upvarphi}{\mathrod}{lettersA}{39}

These lines work for me, unless this \upvarphi does not look likes an italic character.