# What font combination produces these math symbols?

Tags: fonts, greek, stix

I have an article that is in press but the editorial has messed up all the symbols in figures (symbols used are not the same as in the LaTeX main document). I would like to know if I can find out what packages are used to create the symbols in the attached image so I can recreate all figures. The bold symbols seem to be from the `stix` package, but I have no idea how to recreate the greek symbols. I found [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/487710/a-whole-list-of-math-fonts-for-greek-letters-in-latex) with a lot of different greek alphabets but none of them seems to match the one they use in this Springer journal.

**UPDATE**

This is the output of pdffonts:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
Times-Roman                          Type 1C           Custom           yes no  no     941  0
MarVoSym                             Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes no  no     973  0
Springnew-Regular                    Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes no  no     978  0
Times-Bold                           Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes no  no     977  0
MyriadPro-SemiCn                     Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes no  no     943  0
MyriadPro-Semibold                   Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes no  no     955  0
MyriadPro-SemiboldSemiCn             Type 1C           MacRoman         yes no  no     956  0
MTSYB                                Type 1C           Custom           yes no  yes    957  0
MyriadPro-Bold                       Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes no  no     962  0
MyriadPro-Regular                    Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes no  no     963  0
Times-Italic                         Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes no  no     964  0
MTSYN                                Type 1C           Custom           yes no  yes    965  0
MTMI                                 Type 1C           Custom           yes no  yes    573  0
CMSY10                               Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes no  no     583  0
MTEX                                 Type 1C           Custom           yes no  yes    580  0
MyriadPro-BoldSemiCn                 Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes no  no     584  0
MSBM10                               Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes no  no     588  0
Times-BoldItalic                     Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes no  no     590  0
IEADAM+CMMIB10                       Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no     600  0
IEADBN+CMR7                          Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no     598  0
IEADBO+CMR10                         Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    606  0
IEADBP+CMMI7                         Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no     602  0
RMTMIB                               Type 1C           Custom           yes no  yes    611  0
CMBSY10                              Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes no  no     613  0
MSAM7                                Type 1C           Custom           yes no  no     610  0
bbold10                              Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes no  no     621  0
IEAEBO+CMSY7                         Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    626  0
CMSY8                                Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes no  no     627  0
Times-RomanSmallCaps                 Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes no  no     630  0
IEAEJO+CMMI10                        Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    631  0
CMBX10                               Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes no  no     637  0
IEAJED+CMSY10                        Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    638  0
IEALNF+Times-Roman                   Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no     640  0
IEBELP+CMR8                          Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no     646  0
CMSY6                                Type 1C           Custom           yes no  no     647  0
IEBEMB+CMR6                          Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no     648  0
CMR9                                 Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes no  no     645  0
IEBEMD+CMMI9                         Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    649  0
CMMI6                                Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes no  no     650  0
CMMI8                                Type 1C           Custom           yes no  yes    651  0
CMMIB8                               Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes no  no     652  0
Times-Bold                           Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes no  no     653  0
```

[image]

Comment: do you have pdf?, If so you can get the font list from `pdffonts` or the viewer font menu, you don't need to guess.

Comment: Springer has its own variations of Times. So no hope to fully reproduce them.

Comment: It's Springer, so I guess I'm out of luck?

Comment: The Gamma in NewTX can pass; not the `\partial` symbol, nor the Omega, I'm afraid. Use NewTX.

Comment: Hope these are the old fonts of `mathtime` which from very old `Y&Y` format....

Comment: Special case of [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture).

Answer (score 1):

If someone ever comes along this question:

One easy way to inspect a pdf like this is opening it in Inkscape, then mark the text in question with the text tool. Even if you don't have the font, Inkscape tells you, which font it would like to have, giving you at least the name.

Comment: Looks like this is not covered in the general question [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture). Why don't you move it there.