# Insert specific form of tau

Tags: pdftex, symbols, luatex, amsmath, greek

I want to insert this specific tau in my paper
[image].
But with the usual tau symbol, I am getting this tau,[image]. Wth the upgreek package, I am getting this, [image].

Therefore I am asking for your guidance about the proper package to insert the appropriate tau.

Comment: Surely this is just a matter of picking the right font? Take a look: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/487710/a-whole-list-of-math-fonts-for-greek-letters-in-latex

Comment: That's the `\tau`from e.g. `mathptmx`.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Ingmar.

Comment: Thank you @campa. mathptmx worked fine for me.

Comment: If you are using LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX you can use package `unicode-math` to load for greek math symbols whatever font you want and so you can pick the tau you like. If you need more details please let me know.

Comment: There's [How to look up a symbol or identify a letter from a math alphabet or other character? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-letter-from-a-math-alphabet-or-other-chara/21#21) but doesn't seem to help in this case.