# SVG output from Metapost with opentype fonts

Tags: metapost, svg, opentype

Is there any way to produce SVG output from Metapost and use opentype fonts for labels (like luatex allows with luamplib and pdf output)?

Comment: The manual is about Metapost, it can produce svg output with regular TeX fonts. Luatex gives a way to use opentype fonts, but AFAIK outputs pdf.  And my question is if it is possible to get svg _with_ opentype fonts.

Comment: Ah, sorry! The program doesn’t seem to support that, other than converting the OpenType font to Type 1. If there’s a better way, please let me know!

Comment: No, the SVG backend has been removed from `mplib` and normal MetaPost can't use OpenType fonts.  You can generate PDF from LuaTeX and `mplib` and convert that into SVG.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/489244/is-there-a-way-to-render-a-tex-formula-in-pure-html-css-using-open-type-fonts/489264#489264 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361930/svg-output-and-luatex/474443#474443

Comment: Thank you, Henri! Can the first approach be used together with luatex to get <text>...</text> fields and embedded fonts in SVG (not just letters' paths) with metapost graphics?