# TeX Gyre Pagella Math Integral sign much too small

Tags: math-mode, luatex, unicode-math, tex-gyre-math

I am writing my thesis and I use the TeX Gyre Pagella Math fonts, but I have noticed that the integral sign is much too small compared to fractions.

[image]

as you can see in the above image. I am using LuaLaTeX.

Is there any way to make the integral sign a more sensible size?

A minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math Regular}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    f(a) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{z-a}\mathrm d z
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Load `relsize` and try `\mathlarger{\int}`?

Comment: Could we please see a full minimal example, so others can test

Comment: You can also try Asana Math, which also bases its letters on Palatino.

Comment: All tex gyre math fonts have this problem, so I never use them. Maybe they should build a new release.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply adjust the `DisplayOperatorMinHeight` font parameter.  That also indicates that the font is broken.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\everydisplay{\Umathoperatorsize\displaystyle=5ex}
\begin{document}

\[\int_\gamma\frac{f(x)}{z-a}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to selectively enlarge the integral sign in some equations only using your method?

Comment: `Undefined control sequence.
<inserted text> \Umathoperatorsize` on xelatex

Comment: @1900011604 Yes. Did you read the question? It's even tagged with [tag:luatex].

Comment: Thanks! On xelatex here, same problem. TeX Gyre *** Math Integral sign all much too small

Answer (score 5):

with xelatex you get

[image]

but with lualatex you get

[image]

from

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}[range=\int,Scale=2]


\begin{document}

\[\int_\gamma\frac{f(x)}{z-a}\]

\end{document}
```

I'm not sure if the difference is in `unicode-math` or the underlying `luatex` math rendering, the scaled font for `\int` has caused the math parameters used for fraction spacing (and other things) to be scaled. I'll ping Will...

as Ulrike points out you can reset the parameters with an additional mathfont setting, resulting in

[image]

which doesn't produce quite the result xetex does but usable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}[range=\int,Scale=2]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}[range=\sum]


\begin{document}

\[\int_\gamma\frac{f(x)}{z-a}\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: a scale of 2 is too big in any case, but used to magnify the effect here.

Comment: The last math font sets the math fontdimens etc, so add e.g. `\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}[range=\sum]` as last entry.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer ah I tried setting the whole thing again but that undid the scale...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer still doesn't get it quite right, I'll add an image

Comment: I can stretch the integral with `\Uleft\Udelimiter "0 "0 "00222B` (and a accompaigning \Uright. after the frac), but the subscript is at the wrong position.

Comment: With `Scale=2` the font weight is a bit over-exaggerated.

Comment: @HenriMenke unusably distorted might be a more accurate way to describe it, with xetex you might get away with 1.2 though.

Comment: Are you familiar with a place to report bugs with the TeX Gyre fonts?

Comment: @msx the project is based here http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tg-math/index_html but I'm not sure of  the preferred reporting mechanism

Answer (score 5):

\Uhextensible seems to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}


\begin{document}
\[\int _\gamma\frac{f(x)}{z-a}\]

\[ \Uhextensible width 2ex "0 "00222B_\gamma\frac{f(x)}{z-a}\]

\end{document}
```

But I have no idea why and  which width is sensible.

[image]

After a bit digging in the context code I found also an (undocumented) `\Uvextensible` which looks more sensible:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}


\begin{document}
\[\int _\gamma\frac{f(x)}{z-a}\]

\[ \mathop{\Uvextensible height 15pt depth 15pt exact axis\Udelimiter "0 "0 "222B}\nolimits_\gamma\frac{f(x)}{z-a}\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: The subscript position is wrong.

Comment: @HenriMenke I'm not quite happy with it either. The code in context (\autointegral) forces \limits with the comment that "\nolimits is difficult because of kerning problems".  But simply making the integral always large doesn't look good either too.

Answer (score 0):

The following takes the integrals from libertinus math:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[libertinus]{pagella-otf}

\begin{document}
\[
    f(a) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{z-a}\mathrm d z
\]

the old behaviour:
\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}
\[
f(a) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{z-a}\mathrm d z
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hum… I get `Error: Unknown option libertinus for package pagella-otf.`   This option is not mentioned in the `pagella-otf` documentation.

Comment: you need version 0.02: https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/pagella-otf  I suppose it is not mirrored on all machines, hopefully for tomorrow