# umathcode by glyph slot

Tags: xetex, unicode-math

In XeXeX I can input a glyph by the glyph ID `\XeTeXglyph4185\relax`

However, when I try to define a math character, no character is inserted: `\Umathchardef\myint 0 0 4185`

If I instead use `\Umathchardef\myint 0 0 "222B` then I get the standard unicode integral. However, I of course want a different symbol.

I have tried reading the XeTeX reference pdf, but I am unable to figure out what values for  ⟨math type⟩ ⟨fam.⟩ I should use.

```
\documentclass[]{report}


\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont[]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont[
mathrm = sym,
mathup = sym,
mathit = sym,
mathbf = sym,
mathbf = sym,
math-style = TeX,
bold-style = TeX,
]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}


\AtBeginDocument{%
  \Umathchardef\myint 0 0 4185
}
\begin{document}

{\XeTeXglyph4185\relax

\( \myint \)

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's not supported. If the font doesn't map the glyph to some Unicode codepoints then you can't use it in mathchardef.

Comment: I see. Is there a standard way to do what I'm asking then? (i.e. to define this command). I figure I could modify the font file or to just use XeTeXglyph inside `\text` in mathmode.

Comment: Quite likely the glyph was added with the idea of making a style selection feature, but the idea was never implemented.

Comment: @tch How willing are you to use LuaLaTeX instead?

Comment: Based on some other answers on this site I plan to try it out. I'm quite willing to use it as long as it doesn't take too much trouble to get my document to compile.

Comment: @tch That integral sign is huge. Do you really want to use it in inline math? Or do you want to use it in display math? Do you want e.g. \sum to be so big too?

Comment: I was just using this particular integral size as an example. I want to use a somewhat larger size than the default in display math.

Comment: I ended up switching to lualatex and it woks fine after applying the fix from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/489859/tex-gyre-pagella-math-integral-sign-much-too-small. Thanks!