# How to get a more beautiful 'v' symbol in math mode

Tags: math-fonts

I would like to obtain a letter 'v' in math mode that would look like this[image: v for the velocity vector].
The default $v$ is round (so it doesn't look like a $\nu$), but I don't find it so pretty.
I've tried every math package I know, the closest I've got is the $v$ of the {txfonts} package, but it's still note what I'm looking for (this one actually looks a bit too much like $\nu$).

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  I'm afraid you've got a tough search ahead of you.  This has been a problem since math was committed to print.

Comment: Someone should mention https://ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive?lang=en

Comment: where did you get the image, of you have that as pdf you can see which font it is

Comment: I found this in a YouTube video

Answer (score 1):

In the modern toolchain with `unicode-math`, that somewhat vaguely resembles STIX Two Math, stylistic set 2. There’s a survey of OpenType math fonts [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425098/which-opentype-math-fonts-are-available) that we try to keep up-to-date.

If there’s an italic text font you like, you can use it in math mode with `\setmathfont[range=it, Scale=MatchLowercase]{Some Font in Italic}`, with `mathastext`, or with `mathspec` in XeLaTeX.

For a font specimen of legacy packages, you might want to look through [this great survey.](https://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-1/hartke/hartke.pdf)  It’s from 2006, so it doesn’t show `newtxmath`, `newpxmath` or their many options, `eulerpx`, or a few others.