# How can I get this sum symbol?

Tags: symbols, math-operators

I want to get this sum symbol

[image]

I tried differents fonts but I din't find it

Comment: Use `\usepackage{unicode-math} \setmathfont{XITS Math}`, then compile with xelatex or lualatex. Related: [Which OpenType Math fonts are available?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/425099).