# Custom font does not support numbers in math mode

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I was trying to change fonts in my document but run into some problems:

1. It seems that the custom font I am using does not support numbers (and symbols) in math mode and instead the default font is being used.
2. The same problems appears in the axes: ticks values are displayed in the default font and not in the custom font.

I know for sure that all the fonts in question (and especially Harding Text Web that I am using for maths) support all the symbols, greek letters, and numbers that I would ever need in my document.

My intention is to use some of the fonts I have installed on my computer. I am aware that I could e.g. swap my 'system' `Roboto` to the `roboto` TeX package. But this is impossible with some other fonts. 
Something I noticed: using the ASCII symbol for e.g. sigma inside\mathrm works, but \sigma reverts to the default font anyway. I do not see myself looking up all the UTF/ASCII codes for all symbols and numbers...
I am using TeXShop with XeLaTeX.

[image: Excerpt from the document]

*Notice how the zeros, infinity symbol, and the greek letters are in Computer Modern*

My code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

%----- Custom font -------------
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Harding Text Web}
\setsansfont{Roboto} 
\setmonofont{Hack}
%-------------------------------


%----- Include maths -----
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%-------------------------


%----- Sans math, math as text --------
\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}
\usepackage{sfmath}
%--------------------------------------


%----- Custom commands -------------
\newcommand{\T}{\textrm{\sf T}}
\newcommand{\A}{\mathbf{A}}
\newcommand{\B}{\mathbf{B}_\kappa}
\newcommand{\uk}{\mathbf{u}_\kappa}
\newcommand{\de}{\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\trace}{\mathrm{Tr}}
\newcommand{\Gramian}{\textbf{W}_{\rm c}}
\newcommand{\vect}{\mathrm{vec}}
%-----------------------------------


\begin{document}



\subsection*{Normalization}

$$ \A_{\rm norm} = \frac{\A}{\lambda(\A)_{\rm max} + c} - \textbf{I} $$
%
where $\lambda(\A)_{\rm max}$ denotes the largest eigenvalue of $\A$ and $\textbf{I}$ is the identity matrix. 

\subsection*{Controllability Gramian}

$$ \Gramian = \int_{0}^{\infty} \exp(\A\tau)\B\B^\T \exp(\A^\T\tau) \de \tau $$
%
where $^\T$ denotes the transpose of a matrix.

Alternatively, we can obtain the controllability Gramian $ \textbf{W}_{\rm c} $ by solving the Lyapunov equation:
%
$$ \A\textbf{W}_{\rm c} + \textbf{W}_{\rm c}\A^\T + \B\B^\T = 0$$
%
limitation being that it can be only applied to stable systems.

\end{document}
```

Comment: math font setup and text font setup are two quite different things. Providing symbols is not enough: A math font needs a number of additional font dimension which are typically not present in a text fonts. While it is possible to exchange many of the math symbols by symbols taken from the text font, it is imho better to use a real math font with unicode math everywhere and stick to it.

Comment: Okay, so I found a workaround: I took my .ttf and constructed a font family (.tfm, .fd, etc.) from scratch using this script: https://devnotcorp.wordpress.com/2011/06/10/use-truetype-font-with-pdflatex/. Thanks for help!

Comment: as far as I can see the script only creates a text font (T1-encoding), this won't help for various math symbols either.

Comment: It solved the problem that the numbers in math mode were drawn from Computer Modern (in LaTeX). In XeLaTeX, I am getting a better support and range of symbols, but numbers and symbols are still in CM... However, when I use \textrm (or \textit) in math mode all numbers and symbols are drawn from the custom font and everything works. Perhaps I will just need a macro that will append \textit to all equations...

Comment: Exchanging the numbers and other symbols are easier with unicode-math

Comment: Where do you find Harding font? I do not find that in Nature

Answer (score 2):

While I don’t have the fonts to test, the following usually works:

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchUppercase}
\setmainfont{Harding Text Web}[Scale=1.0]
\setsansfont{Roboto} 
\setmonofont{Hack}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[range={scr,bfscr}, StylisticSet=1] % Set up \mathscr and \mathcal
\setmathfont{Harding Text Web}[range=up}
\setmathfont{Harding Text Web Italic}[range=it] % Or whatever the Italic font is called.
\setmathfont{Harding Text Web Bold}[range=bfup]
\setmathfont{Harding Text Web Bold Italic}[range=bfit]
% Similarly set sfup, sfit, bfsfup, bfsfit and tt if you need them.
```

You might find [another math font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425098/which-opentype-math-fonts-are-available) that matches Harding Text better.  In particular, [it has a high x-height, a flared style, and avoids thin stems.](https://commercialtype.com/news/harding_a_new_typeface_for_nature) You might try TeX Gyre Bonum Math, TeX Gyre Schola Math or TeX Gyre DejaVu Math.