# Curly letters used by John Lee in "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds"

Tags: symbols

John Lee (Introduction to Smooth Manifolds) seems to use some package that Detexify doesn't know for his curly letters. Here are some examples:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Does anyone know how to generate these letters?

Answer (score 12):

According to mathalpha's [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathalpha), it seems that this is Mathtime Pro 2 script, which is a commercial (i.e., not free) font.
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I was also searching for some letters from another book (Nakahara) and I found them in the documentation, too :) (Nakahara's symbols are contained in the Euler script.)

Comment: More precisely, the glyphs in the OP's screenshot are from the **bold** caligraphic font family of the `mtpro2` package. If you have access to the full (non-free) version of this package, you would load it with the option `mtpcal` and generate the letters by writing (in math mode) `\mathbcal{B}`, `\mathbcal{D}`, `\mathbcal{L}`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't this one? Maybe [you should search for some different font for the exact shape](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425098/which-opentype-math-fonts-are-available), but...

[image]

Comment: This is for your new gravatar...very nice "lupo alberto?" :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano no, still scrat ... but well, Lupo Alberto è un buon suggerimento... ci penserò!

Comment: Ahahahahah :-) :-)