# unicode-math with greek letters upright and latin letters italic

Tags: xetex, unicode-math

I am using `unicode-math` to select math fonts in XeLaTeX. From the documentation, I see there are four options for `math-style`:

- `ISO` has all letters, Greek and Latin, italic
- `TeX` has all letters italic except uppercase Greek, which are upright
- `french` has all letters upright except lowercase latin, which are italic
- `upright` has all letters upright

Would it be possible to set all Latin letters italic and all Greek letters upright?

The reason I need this setting is that I'm using Garamond-Math and I don't like the italic Greek letters of this font, so an alternative solution could be taking Greek letters from another font, but I haven't been able to do it. Here is my setting:

```
\usepackage[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Garamond-Math.otf}[StylisticSet={5,7,9}]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}[range=it/{Greek,greek}]
```

Comment: I can’t duplicate your bug. The `\setmathfont` example worked for me in LuaLaTeX on TeX Live 2020.

Comment: A way to do it might be to load an upright font (such as Neo Euler) over `range=it/{Greek,greek}`, which forces you to use `\mathit` if you actually do want slanted Greek math letters.

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. After some debugging, I realized this is because I also used the `version=sansserif` option for another math font, and this interacts badly with the `range` option. So, apparently, I cannot have both `range` and `version` in the same document. Too bad

Comment: Unfortunately, that’s correct. There’s a warning buried in the `unicode-math` manual. You can, however, select a sans-serif math font without `version=` (Fira Math or KPMath-Sans`).

Comment: Do you need to switch between serif and sans-serif math in the same document? In the same section of the document?

Comment: Yes. I am preparing a book and figure/tables captions are in sans, so whenever I have a math symbol in the caption, it must be sans. I think this is quite a common situation. I haven't been able to select a second math font to be used only for sans, how can I do it?

Comment: Use `version=` without `range=`. `\setmathfont{KpMath-Regular.otf}\setmathfont[version=bold]{KpMath-Bold.otf}\setmathfont[version=sans]{KpMath-Sans.otf}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the booleans mentioned by David in the document. Be aware that this are internal commands of unicode-math, so it would be good to make a feature request for an official interface:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_gset_false:N  \g__um_upGreek_bool %or true
\bool_gset_true:N   \g__um_upgreek_bool %or false
\bool_gset_true:N   \g__um_uplatin_bool %or false
%more if needed ...
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setmathfont{Garamond-Math.otf}[StylisticSet={5,7,9}]


\begin{document}

$a\alpha\Gamma$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The options you mention just set boolean flags so it should be easy enough to add another option with a different combination

```
      {ISO} {
             \bool_gset_false:N \g__um_bfliteral_bool
             \bool_gset_false:N \g__um_bfupGreek_bool
             \bool_gset_false:N \g__um_bfupgreek_bool
             \bool_gset_false:N \g__um_bfupLatin_bool
             \bool_gset_false:N \g__um_bfuplatin_bool
            }
      {TeX} {
             \bool_gset_false:N \g__um_bfliteral_bool
             \bool_gset_true:N  \g__um_bfupGreek_bool
             \bool_gset_false:N \g__um_bfupgreek_bool
             \bool_gset_true:N  \g__um_bfupLatin_bool
             \bool_gset_true:N  \g__um_bfuplatin_bool
            }
  {upright} {
             \bool_gset_false:N \g__um_bfliteral_bool
             \bool_gset_true:N  \g__um_bfupGreek_bool
             \bool_gset_true:N  \g__um_bfupgreek_bool
             \bool_gset_true:N  \g__um_bfupLatin_bool
             \bool_gset_true:N  \g__um_bfuplatin_bool
            }
  {literal} {
             \bool_gset_true:N  \g__um_bfliteral_bool
            }
```

Comment: Thank you, and sorry if this further question sounds naive, but is it possible to add an option without modifying the .sty file? Or should I just add the new list of boolean flags in the preamble?

Comment: probably but not tonight, really I would have left this just as a comment but too much code to make the comment readable, I may post an answer later if no one else has (I'd have to look where best to patch this in)  @Massimo

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, you might have an [XY-problem.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)  What you say you want is sans-serif math for captions.  The problem you’re having is that `unicode-math` supports **either** `range=` or `version=`, but not both together.  (There’s a warning about this buried in the manual.)

If that’s what you actually want, load a sans-serif math font with `version=`, and don’t use `range=`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{KpRoman}
\setsansfont{KpSans}
\setmonofont{KpMono}
\setmathfont{KpMath-Regular}
\setmathfont{KpMath-Bold}[version=bold]
\setmathfont{KpMath-Sans}[version=sans]

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\mathversion{sans}}

\begin{document}
\section*{Isn’t \(\mathbb{R}^3\) Wonderful?}

Truly, \(\mathbb{R}^3\) is.
\end{document}
```

[image: KP-fonts sample]

Unfortunately, [you’re not spoiled for choice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425098/which-opentype-math-fonts-are-available) when it comes to sans-serif math fonts.

It’s trivial to define `\sansversion` analogous to `\boldversion`, and you can also adapt the `\boldsymbol` code from `amsbsy.sty` to a `\sanssymbol` command if you need to be able to switch to sans-serif math within an expression.  Otherwise, set the formatting of captions and whatever else you want to be sans-serif to `\sffamily\mathversion{sans}`.

If you already knew this and you were just asking how you can change the Greek letters in your math font, without using `range=`, one way to do that would be to define a new `\setmathfontface` or math `version=` that selects your alternative Greek font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{EBGaramond}[Scale=1.0]
\setsansfont{KpSans}
\setmonofont{KpMono}
\setmathfont{Garamond-Math}
\setmathfont{KpMath-Sans}[version=sans]
\setmathfontface{\altgreek}{GFS Olga}

\newcommand\altGamma{\altgreek{\mupGamma}}
\newcommand\altzeta{\altgreek{\mupzeta}}

\begin{document}
Truly, \(\altGamma(\altzeta)\) is wonderful.
\end{document}
```

[image: EB Garamond/GFS Olga sample]

Comment: Thank you. I already knew the first solution. The problem is that I want both things, a math sans face *and* a different font for greek. Your (second) solution with `\setmathfontface` seems to work, although it requires that I redefine all Greek letters I'm using.