# How do I write a cursive U in math mode for uncertainty sets?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

[image]

I can find fancier cursive U's, but I can't find this exact one.  \mathcal{U} wasn't just right.

Comment: Please, add some code to show what you're doing, because the simple `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}$\mathcal{U}$\end{document}` produces [this picture (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3h8OS.png) which is *very much* alike the one you want.

Answer (score 4):

If you’re using LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you want to load `unicode-math` and [a math font of your choice.](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/unicodetex/latex/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdff#14)  The default Latin Modern Math `\mathcal` is pretty close in that specimen sheet, but you could use, for example, the `\mathcal` from STIX Two Math with:

```
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[
   range={cal,bfcal},
   Scale=MatchUppercase ]
```

There’s a more complete list of OpenType math fonts that you can try [on this site.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425098/which-opentype-math-fonts-are-available)

With PDFTeX, the best way to change supplementary math alphabets is [`mathalpha`.  The manual has](https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mathalpha/doc/mathalpha-doc.pdf) a comprehensive set of specimens, but you might try

```
\usepackage[cal=esstix]{mathalpha}
```

with a `calscaled=` parameter if you need to adjust the size.

Comment: Thanks!  I think I understand the problem now.  I'm using Jupyter Notebooks which has STIX fonts installed by default.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28909747/how-do-i-configure-mathjax-for-ipython-notebooks gives good instructions on how to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using OpTeX, then load appropriate Unicode font family and use `{\cal U}` or directly . For example:

```
\fontfam[lmfonts]

... subject to $f_i(x,u)\le 0$ for $u\in{\cal U}$, $i=1,\dots,m$.

or

... subject to $f_i(x,u) ≤ 0$ for $u ∈ $, $i = 1,\dots, m$.

\bye
```

Answer (score 1):

Off-topic...I think..But if you want to create your image in `LaTeX` code you can use `optidef` package that it is specific.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{optidef}

\begin{document}
\begin{mini}<b>
{}{f_0(x)}{}{}
\addConstraint {f_i(x,u)}{\le 0\text{ for all } u\in\mathcal{U},\,}{i=1,\ldots,m}
\end{mini}
\end{document}
```

[image]