# High-quality OpenType/TrueType fonts for text and math showcase

Tags: xetex, luatex, typography, opentype, truetype

Is there any showcase of common high-quality OpenType/TrueType fonts for text and math (probably mostly serif)? I have been trying to find such here, but no success. Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/425098/134574?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have made such a showcase, you can find it here:
http://daniel.flipo.free.fr/doc/luatex/fonts.pdf

Some examples of math fonts can be found at the end of this document:
http://daniel.flipo.free.fr/doc/luatex/pdf2lua.pdf

Both documents are in French…

See also this answer: [Which OpenType Math fonts are available?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425098/which-opentype-math-fonts-are-available)

Answer (score 4):

The OTF fonts available in TeXlive are summarized in [OpTeX fonts catalog](https://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/optex/op-catalog.pdf)