# Larger concrete fonts

Tags: fonts, fontsize, math-fonts

The [concrete roman font](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/concmath/concmath.pdf) designed by D. Knuth is a lovely one. I am looking for a way for it to be larger.

The current header I have is as follows

```
\documentclass[15pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools}
\usepackage{thmtools, thm-restate}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{eulervm,eucal,eufrak}% the math fonts used in concrete mathematics
\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage{concrete}% the concrete-roman, used in concrete mathematics
\usepackage{lipsum,hyperref,datetime2}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
```

#### Attempts made

I have tried changing `[15pt]` in `\documentclass[15pt]` to `[17pt]` or `[25pt]`. It did not change any thing in the pdf file. I have also tried configuring with `\usepackage[20pt]{concrete}` and `\usepackage[fontsize=20pt]{concrete}` - also in vain.

#### Question

How to effectively change the font size for the document over all? I'm afraid I must figure a way to configure as well
`\usepackage{eulervm,eucal,eufrak}`.

Comment: `article` doesn't have a 15pt option (unrelated to which fonts you use) you can use a class that does, eg extarticle or other classes with a larger size range eg memoir or koma or simply use `\Large` after begin {document}`

Comment: note you would get a larger font by changing `15pt` to `12pt` (as `15pt` does not do anything so you are getting 10pt)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Indeed! Your comment resolves my problem exactly. I hope to be able to find this sort of things out independently next time. What do you recommend me to read? For example, where should I read how `article` and `extarticle` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not provide a test file but a document such as

```
\documentclass[15pt]{article}

\begin{document}

abc
\end{document}
```

Produces the warning

```
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [15pt].
```

and so produces the default 10pt font. So you could get a larger font by using the `12pt` option

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

abc
\end{document}
```

Note the options `10pt`, `11pt` and `12pt` are *option names* they only look like lengths as a hint to what they do. The `11pt` option for example doesn't set any font sizes to 11pt it sets the default size to 10.95pt. More generally they do not just set the main document size, the options affect the whole design changing all the font sizes, changing the text width, changing spacing around lists and displayed equations etc.

The extsizes collection includes classes that are essentially copies of the standard article/report/book with a larger range of size options (up to 20pt) so you could also use

```
\documentclass[15pt]{extarticle}

\begin{document}

abc
\end{document}
```

See the documentation which is probably available on your system as `texdoc extarticle`

Other classes such as memoir or Komascript classes also have larger size ranges.

Answer (score 3):

There is a scalable version of Concrete in `ccfonts`.

You might also want a sans-serif companion font for headers.  DEK, in the book he originally commissioned Concrete for, *Concrete Mathematics*, used Computer Modern Sans-Serif semibold condensed.

Also keep in mind that there are only a few fixed size options in the default classes.  In this example, I load Koma-script to enable arbitrary scaling.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=15pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb} % Load before ccfonts
\usepackage[boldsans, exscale]{ccfonts} % Boldsans enables cmss demi-condensed.
\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage{eucal, eufrak} % Or mathalpha

\setkomafont{disposition}{\fontfamily{cmss}\fontseries{sbc}}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\(  x = \frac{{-}b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a} \)
\end{document}
```

[image: ccfonts + eulervm sample]

If you can use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, [my answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425098/which-opentype-math-fonts-are-available) has been turned into a package, `\usepackage[neoeuler]{fontsetup}`.  This requires you to download [the free Neo Euler font.](https://github.com/khaledhosny/euler-otf)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, maybe?  Of course, things like `\Large`, `\small`, etc., are not changed by this approach.

```
\documentclass[15pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools}
\usepackage{thmtools, thm-restate}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{eulervm,eucal,eufrak}% the math fonts used in concrete mathematics
\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage{concrete}% the concrete-roman, used in concrete mathematics
\usepackage{lipsum,hyperref,datetime2}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\mdseries}
\begin{document}
\section{Section title}
Hello world $y=mx + b$.

\fontsize{15pt}{17pt}\selectfont\noindent
Hello world $y=mx + b$.

\end{document}
```

[image]