# How to import a certain open math font (Xepersian)

Tags: unicode-math, math-fonts, xepersian

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany,12pt]{book}           
\usepackage[a]{esvect}                                
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}                       
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amsfonts}                   
\usepackage{mathrsfs,mathtools}                                                                               
\usepackage{fontenc}                                   
\usepackage{geometry}                           
\usepackage{fontspec}                    
\RequirePackage{hyperref}                    
\usepackage{etoolbox}           
\usepackage[computeautoilg=off]{xepersian}                   
\settextfont[Scale=1.1]{IRXLotus}                                                      
\setdigitfont[Scale=1.1]{IRXLotus}                  
\setlatintextfont[Scale=1.1]{Times New Roman}                 
\begin{document}               
\chapter{بردارهای ویژه و مقادیر ویژه}                             
    بردار $\mathbf{x}$ و $\mathbf{y}$    بر حسب پایه‌ای متعامد از فضای $\mathfrak{L}$ با مجموع حاصل‌ضرب دوبه‌دو متناظر مختصات آن‌ها به‌دست می‌آید. حال $\mathbf{x}$ را از $\mathfrak{L}$ بگیرید. اگر $\mathop{\xi_i=(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{e}_i)}_{(1 \leqslant i \leqslant n)}$ فرض شود، آنگاه
    \begin{equation*}
        \mathbf{x}=\xi_1 \mathbf{e}_1 +\cdots +\xi_n \mathbf{e}_n
    \end{equation*}
    و علت این است که
    \begin{equation*}
        (\mathbf{x},\mathbf{e}_i)=\displaystyle\xi_1 (\mathbf{e}_1,\mathbf{e}_i) +\cdots +\xi_n (\mathbf{e}_n,\mathbf{e}_i)=\xi_i (\mathbf{e}_i,\mathbf{e})=\xi_i (\mathbf{e}_i ,\mathbf{e}_i)=\xi_i (\mathbf{e}_i,\mathbf{e}_i )= \xi_i.
    \end{equation*}                                 
\end{document}
```

I would like to import certain open math fonts for mathematical objects as suggested in this neat [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/425099/59624). It seems that they work under `unicode-math` package but, in this minimal work it crashed. May I ask you what to do? Thanks for your effort and the TIME!

Comment: not related but don't use `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` with xelatex (it does nothing other than generate a warning that it should not be used)

Comment: also `\displaystyle` does nothing at the point you have used it (equations are in displaystyle by default)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks so much for the points!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not provided any example of the problem or showed what error you got. It is hard to debug "it crashed" without knowing what the input was.

I don't have the fonts you used, but if I switched fonts and added a couple of fixes for xepersion being incompatible with current latex loading `unicode-math` gives no error.

In comments you said you wanted Asana-Math, so:

[image]

If you edit the question to show an example of the problem, it would be easier to debug.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany,12pt]{book}           
\usepackage[a]{esvect}                                
%\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}                       
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amsfonts}                   
\usepackage{mathrsfs,mathtools}                                                                               
\usepackage{fontenc}                                   
\usepackage{geometry}                           
\usepackage{fontspec}                    
\RequirePackage{hyperref}                    
\usepackage{etoolbox}           
\usepackage[computeautoilg=off]{xepersian}
% https://github.com/persiantex/xepersian/issues/17
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \etex_iffontchar:D \tex_iffontchar:D 
\def\c_one{1~}
\ExplSyntaxOff                    
\settextfont[Scale=1.1]{Arial}%{IRXLotus}                                                      
\setdigitfont[Scale=1.1]{Arial}%{IRXLotus}                                                                  
\setlatintextfont[Scale=1.1]{Times New Roman} 

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Asana-Math.otf}
               
\begin{document}               
\chapter{بردارهای ویژه و مقادیر ویژه}                             
    بردار $\mathbf{x}$ و $\mathbf{y}$    بر حسب پایه‌ای متعامد از فضای $\mathfrak{L}$ با مجموع حاصل‌ضرب دوبه‌دو متناظر مختصات آن‌ها به‌دست می‌آید. حال $\mathbf{x}$ را از $\mathfrak{L}$ بگیرید. اگر $\mathop{\xi_i=(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{e}_i)}_{(1 \leqslant i \leqslant n)}$ فرض شود، آنگاه
    \begin{equation*}
        \mathbf{x}=\xi_1 \mathbf{e}_1 +\cdots +\xi_n \mathbf{e}_n
    \end{equation*}
    و علت این است که
    \begin{equation*}
        (\mathbf{x},\mathbf{e}_i)=\displaystyle\xi_1 (\mathbf{e}_1,\mathbf{e}_i) +\cdots +\xi_n (\mathbf{e}_n,\mathbf{e}_i)=\xi_i (\mathbf{e}_i,\mathbf{e})=\xi_i (\mathbf{e}_i ,\mathbf{e}_i)=\xi_i (\mathbf{e}_i,\mathbf{e}_i )= \xi_i.
    \end{equation*}                                 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear David, I am interested to use `Asana Math` fonts. I don't know where to insert the codes as written in noted answer. This is my problem. Sorry!

Comment: @Mikasa so was your error `! Package fontspec Error: The font "Asana Math" cannot be found.` ?

Comment: @Mikasa you should just need `\setmathfont{Asana-Math.otf}` after loading `unicode-math` but the font seems missing in texlive, if you download AsanaMath.otf from https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/Asana-Math then it will work (I'm checking why the font is not there)

Comment: I assumed to add the codes `\setmainfont[Ligatures={Common,Rare,TeX}]{TeX Gyre Pagella}` and `\setmathfont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Asana Math}` after the line 18. So I got empty boxes in output instead of words and maths objects. May I add a picture below in `answer your question` for a while to illustrate better?

Comment: you don't want `\setmainfont[Ligatures={Common,Rare,TeX}]{TeX Gyre Pagella}` that will make the main font Pagella which has no Persian, just simply add `\setmathfont{Asana Math}`

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!! I got that David. Thanks for taking me out of darkness! :)

Comment: Beautiful response. One question: but in Arabic should they use the letters i, j as subscripts and not the Arabic characters ones? :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks for the comment :-) He deserved more than I said. About your question: I don't know the way of that in Arabic (or Arabic academic world) but in in Persian (I mean in Iran) it is acceptable and Xepersian does for us.

Comment: @Mikasa Ah, I not known it. Excuse me :-(