# Font shape `TU/LatinModernMath(1)/b/n' undefined(Font) using `TU/LatinModernMath(1)/m/n' instead

Tags: fonts, fontspec, latin-modern, tabularray

In the following, the row command `row{1} = {font=\boldmath\bfseries}` gets me this error

> Font shape `TU/LatinModernMath(1)/b/n' undefined(Font) using` TU/LatinModernMath(1)/m/n' instead

so, how can I fix it?

```
\documentclass{article}

\tracinglostchars=3 
\usepackage[english, bidi = basic, layout = lists]{babel}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX }

\babelprovide[import, onchar = ids fonts, mapdigits]{arabic}

\babelfont{rm}[Ligatures={Common,Rare}, Scale=1.0, Language=Default]{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}[Language=Default]{ScheherazadeNew}

\babelfont{sf}[Ligatures={Common,Rare}, Language=Default]{Latin Modern Sans}
\babelfont[arabic]{sf}[Language=Default]{ScheherazadeNew}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[bold-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[math-style=ISO]{Latin Modern Math}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{ colspec = { X },  row{1} = {font=\boldmath\bfseries} }
        $\symbf{\delta_i}$
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Latin Modern Math has no bold variant, so if you want to have a bold math font you need to use a different font. The top answer to the [question listing OpenType math fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425098/which-opentype-math-fonts-are-available) mentions for most fonts if a bold version is available.

Comment: you can simplify your example to `\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[math-style=ISO]{Latin Modern Math}

\begin{document}
$x$ \boldmath $x$
\end{document}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a fake bold version:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{unicode-math} 
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[math-style=ISO,version=normal]  
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[version=bold,math-style=ISO,FakeBold = 3]
\begin{document} 
$x$ \boldmath $x$ 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Will `FakeBold = 3` interfere in any way with `\symbf` that I used in my main question?