# Font shape `TU/Montserrat(0)/bx/n' undefined. using `TU/Montserrat(0)/m/n' instead

Tags: fonts

My `montserrat` font is working great but I'm getting the warning

```
Font shape `TU/Montserrat(0)/bx/n' undefined
(Font)  using `TU/Montserrat(0)/m/n' instead.
```

There's a similar post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/619087/font-shape-tu-latinmodernmath1-b-n-undefinedfont-using-tu-latinmodernmath) but I'm not sure how to translate it to fix my warning?

Here's my minimal code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\newfontfamily{\titlefont}{Montserrat}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\bfseries\centering}
    {\huge\chapternumberfont\thechapter}
    {2em}
    {\titlefont\Huge #1}
\begin{document}
\chapter*[Introduction]{Introduction}
Hello
\end{document}
```

Which renders....

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: @egreg Maybe because you have a better install of the Montserrat font? Where did you get it? I got my from fonts.google.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use the TeX Live provided Montserrat font.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newfontfamily{\titlefont}{Montserrat}[
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  ItalicFont=*-Italic,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
]

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\huge\bfseries\titlefont\filcenter}
  {\thechapter}
  {2em}
  {}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

Hello

\end{document}
```

I made a few changes to the `\titleformat` command. You had a `\chapternumberfont` command that's not defined. Since at 12pt base size there's no difference between `\huge` and `\Huge`, the definition can be simplified. No need to use `explicit`. Better to use `titlesec`'s `\filcenter` than `\centering`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I should have posted my output. (I just edited my OP to show what I'm seeing with my code.) Your code fixes my warnings but is much bolder. I'm not sure how to change your code to produce my output.

Comment: @buttonsrtoys Remove `\bfseries`.

Comment: @buttonsrtoys Anyway, the thin font was due to the issue you were describing, because you *did* want boldface: the warning tells exactly that regular font is substituted for boldface.

Comment: Ah. Thank you @egreg! That solved my problem. I'm now warning-free. Thanks for answer and the tips in your post. Much appreciated.