# Change math font to Arial

Tags: luatex, fontspec, math-fonts, arial

I'm working on submitting a manuscript-style scholarship essay, and the formatting must be 12pt Arial. Which I was able to get working using LuaLaTeX. However, once I got that working, I quickly realized the math font looked awkward with the bolder style of Arial.

Can the math font be changed to Arial inside the document? I have always been confused about changing math fonts within LaTeX documents.

How do I change the math font to match something closer to Arials style?

Thanks!

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in
%,showframe
]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{physics}
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{Undergrad Student} % your name here
\rhead{The University}
\usepackage[style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\setlength{\headheight}{12.5pt}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{*.5}{*.5}
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
{\underline{Math in Arial}}
\end{center}
\section{Introduction}
I think the default math font looks odd when paired with Arial. Here is an example: $n = 4$. The math just looks a lot weaker than the text. $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_0^1 x \sin{(x^2-y)}\dd{y}\dd{x}$\\\\
Is there a way to use Arial font for the math symbols? $(n-1) + (2^n + 1) = 2^n + n$\\

\noindent \lipsum[1]


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There aren't many sans math fonts available. See [Which OpenType Math fonts are available?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/425098) for some options. Fira or GFS Neohellenic are probably the only options if you need a full math font.

Comment: But when I try to incorporate them into my document it doesn't work. Adding `\usepackage{unicode-math}` and `\setmathfont{XITS Math}` results in a compilation error that font "XITS Math" cannot be found. I tried this with some of the other ones also, same error. My preamble already utilizes `\usepackage{fontspec}`. Would these clash?

Comment: With `lualatex` it's usually easier to use the actual filename when loading the font. Try e.g. `\setmathfont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{FiraMath-Regular.otf}`. But be careful, as it seems to be missing some characters.

Comment: @AlanMunn I'm considering  fira for a project. Care to elaborate on  missing some characters?

Comment: @daleif Responded in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62596613#62596613).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proper way would be to use `unicode-math` with a sans-serif math font.

However there aren't a lot of sans-serif math fonts available. If you need a specific font family which does not have a math font, you could give the `mathastext` package a try. This will substitute math characters with the letters and numbers from the normal text. The result isn't perfect, but worth trying...

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in
%,showframe
]{geometry}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\usepackage{mathastext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{physics}
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{Undergrad Student} % your name here
\rhead{The University}
\usepackage[style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\setlength{\headheight}{12.5pt}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{*.5}{*.5}
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize\bfseries}

\usepackage{lipsum}



\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\underline{Math in Arial}}
\end{center}
\section{Introduction}
I think the default math font looks odd when paired with Arial. Here is an example: $n = 4$. The math just looks a lot weaker than the text. $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_0^1 x \sin{(x^2-y)}\dd{y}\dd{x}$\\\\
Is there a way to use Arial font for the math symbols? $(n-1) + (2^n + 1) = 2^n + n$\\

\noindent \lipsum[1]


\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you are only worried that Arial looks bolder than your math font, you could try a bolder serif math font. There you'll have a much bigger selection of full-fledged math fonts, e.g.

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in
%,showframe
]{geometry}


\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{physics}
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{Undergrad Student} % your name here
\rhead{The University}
\usepackage[style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\setlength{\headheight}{12.5pt}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{*.5}{*.5}
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize\bfseries}

\usepackage{lipsum}



\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\underline{Math in Arial}}
\end{center}
\section{Introduction}
I think the default math font looks odd when paired with Arial. Here is an example: $n = 4$. The math just looks a lot weaker than the text. $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_0^1 x \sin{(x^2-y)}\dd{y}\dd{x}$\\\\
Is there a way to use Arial font for the math symbols? $(n-1) + (2^n + 1) = 2^n + n$\\

\noindent \lipsum[1]


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This one did the trick `\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}`.

Comment: @Ziggy You're welcome!