# State of sans serif maths fonts

Tags: math-mode, unicode-math, sans-serif, displaystyle

I'm looking for a comprehensive sample of specimens from current, known to be up and running, sans serif fonts for (displaystyle) maths.

In particular, I would like to know how one can know whether a generic font supports maths typesetting.
*e.g.* SF (San Francisco) Pro from apple is pretty neat for typing down notes. What modifications need to be made to that font so that a .tex document (compiled on LuaTex or a modern rendition of Tex with good support for OS fonts) shows maths in a style matching the body font to the closest? Can you extend any font easily with a set of glyphs (possibly of your own design, for your own proprietary use) to have complete maths support, or is that an involved process?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Do you know about the [font catalogue](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/mathfonts.html)?

Answer (score 1):

I can offer an example of how to get sans serif text and math, but not a comprehensive set of samples.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cmbright}

\begin{document}
This is the lead in paragraph.
\[
  x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A more or less comphrehensive list of [available OpenType Math fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425098/which-opentype-math-fonts-are-available) already got compiled. It also includes some sans-serif math fonts such as Fira Math and KpMath Sans. As far as I know extending a font is a very cumbersome task and few fonts provide the symbols defined by the `unicode-math` package.