# Suggest a fitting math font for Sitka (text font)

Tags: fonts, math-fonts

I really like the design of Microsoft's Sitka font. I am searching for a mathematical font that would fit it well.

I use `fontspec` and `unicode-math` to select the fonts.

---

What I've tried so far:

- I enjoy the combination with `euler`; however, its style of numbers is a deal-breaker.
- Pairing with `TeX Gyre Schola Math` is very nice, but there is a mismatch between the ratio of uppercase to lowercase height between the two fonts. It's rather visible in inline math, and I can't manage to fix it with `unicode-math`+`fontspec`. `Schola` was the best fit of all `TeX Gyre … Math` fonts.
- `STIX Two Math` *seems to be a really nice combination.*
- `Latin Modern` and other fonts mentioned on [`unicode-math`'s website](https://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math) range from bad to very bad of a pairing.

### Do you know other mathematical fonts that would be a good fit?

Comment: How about TeX Gyre DejaVu Math or Noto Serif Math? This might help you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425098/which-opentype-math-fonts-are-available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2018 typeface **[Sitka](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/sitka)** was designed by Matthew Carter with the ["mastering" help](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/309754147_Sitka_A_collaboration_between_type_design_and_science) of the founders of Tiro Typeworks: **Ross Mills** and **John Hodson** (op. cit.).

Earlier, the [2016](https://www.stixfonts.org/pressrelease/) [Stipub](https://www.stixfonts.org/) typefaces **S[TIX Two Text](https://github.com/stipub/stixfonts)** and **[STIX Two Math](https://github.com/stipub/stixfonts)** were designed by **Ross Mills** and **John Hudson**. (Other typographers have helped, according to [Github's list of contributors to the STIX2 fonts](https://github.com/stipub/stixfonts).)

Mills and Hudson had implemented Microsoft's [**Cambria Math**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/cambria-math) font (using Jelle Bosma's 2004 [Cambria Text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/cambria) typeface).

Pairing Sitka Text with STIX Two Math (or Cambria) conforms with the heuristic of [selecting font-pairs from the same designer(s)](https://fonts.google.com/knowledge/choosing_type/pairing_typefaces_by_the_same_type_designer_or_type_foundry), here Ross Mills and John Hudson of [Tiro Typeworks](https://www.tiro.com/).