# Bradley Hand Font in Math

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, macos

Compiling with LuaLaTeX, use of Bradley Hand Font works for body and math using beamer;
but I would like to know how to render Bradley Hand font for math using standard Article style. -Thanks.

```
%\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\documentclass{beamer} %
\usefonttheme{serif}%
 \usepackage{fontspec}
 \usepackage{mathpazo}
%\setmainfont{Bradley Hand ITC TT Bold}%used Bold, since that's what was bundled w/ Mac OS X
\setmainfont{BradleyHandITC} %Postscript name of TT added as user font on MacOS X
\begin{document}
\section{Section}
This is a font test. 
\[ E = m c^2 \] 
\[ L = \alpha \int_0^1 \, dx,  \quad  \vec{P} = \int_{0}^{\infty} \sum_{i =1}^{2} {\varphi}_i  d \gamma \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

However when I try to use article style, instead of beamer, the main text is rendered with the font, but the math is not.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
%\documentclass{beamer} 
%\usefonttheme{serif}%
 \usepackage{fontspec}
 \usepackage{mathpazo}
%\setmainfont{Bradley Hand ITC TT Bold}%used Bold, since that's what was bundled w/ Mac OS X
\setmainfont{BradleyHandITC} %Postscript name of TT added as user font on MacOS X

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
This is a font test. 
\[ E = m c^2 \] 
\[ L = \alpha \int_0^1 \, dx,  \quad  \vec{P} = \int_{0}^{\infty} \sum_{i =1}^{2} {\varphi}_i  d \gamma \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

An additional question. How to have only the \section{} and/or selected text use boldface Bradley Hand ITC TT Bold, instead of Regular. -Thanks.

Comment: Off-topic: The `mathpazo` package is very old and borderline obsolete. Do consider replacing `\usepackage{mathpazo}` with either `\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}` or `\usepackage{kpfonts}`.

Comment: -Mico, thanks for the edit and tips on fonts; I do like your suggestions better than mathpazo.  It seems mathpazo works with Bradley Hand in Beamer, but not your suggestions.  Likely need to reverse engineer Beamer font styles to understand what is being done there.

Comment: To turn off Beamer font substitutions, load `\usepackage[professionalfonts]{beamer}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `mathastext` package to get the same behaviour as with beamer, i.e. the symbols in text mode are substituted with symbols from the normal text font:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex 

\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
%\documentclass{beamer} 
%\usefonttheme{serif}%
 \usepackage{fontspec}
 \usepackage{mathpazo}
%\setmainfont{Bradley Hand ITC TT Bold}%used Bold, since that's what was bundled w/ Mac OS X
\setmainfont{Bradley Hand} %Postscript name of TT added as user font on MacOS X

\usepackage{mathastext}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
This is a font test. 
\[ E = m c^2 \] 
\[ L = \alpha \int_0^1 \, dx,  \quad  \vec{P} = \int_{0}^{\infty} \sum_{i =1}^{2} {\varphi}_i  d \gamma \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks samcarter ...

Comment: @LonnyT You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with how the `beamer` document class does its font substitutions. But I can suggest that you load the `unicode-math` package and make use of its `range` machinery, along the lines of the following example.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Bradley Hand Bold} % what's bundled w/ MacOS
\setmathfont{KpMath-Regular}    % set a default math font
\setmathfont{Bradley Hand Bold}[range={up,it}]
%% unicode slots for int, sum, infty, = glyphs:
\setmathfont{Bradley Hand Bold}[range={"222B,"2211,"221E,"003D}] 

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
This is a font test. 
\[ 
E = mc^2, \quad
L = \alpha \int_0^{\,1} dx, \quad  
\vec{P} = \int_{0}^{\,\infty} \sum_{i=1}^2 \varphi_i \, d\gamma 
\]
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If one omits the final `\setmathfont{Bradley Hand Bold}[...]` directive in the code shown above, one would get:

[image]

---

*Second Addendum*: The OP also asked,

> How to have only the `\section` and/or selected text use boldface Bradley Hand ITC TT Bold, instead of Regular?

Assuming you use one of the basic LaTeX document classes, i.e., `article`, `report`, or `book`, or a document class that is based on one of the basic classes, you could use the `sectsty` package to achieve your sectioning-related formatting objective. To use the Bradley Hand Bold font for selected pieces of text, I suggest you employ the `\newfontfamily` machinery of the `fontspec` package.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\bradley}{Bradley Hand Bold} % what's shipped with MacOS

\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\bradley}

\begin{document}
\section{Hello}
\subsection{World}
Once upon a {\bradley time}, there {\bradley was} an enchanted castle \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for instructions on using Unicode.  Is there a place where the different fonts available to Unicode are listed?   For your example, is there a Unicode \setmathfont equivalent to " \usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}", instead of KpMath-Regular, as the math font might be preferable?  thanks again.

Comment: @LonnyT - I'm not aware of a place or document that lists all opentype text-mode and math-mode fonts. Please consult the user guides of the `newpx[text/math]` packages for information on how to load the associated fonts under LuaLaTeX (and XeLaTeX).

Comment: Thanks, I will investigate.

Comment: @LonnyT For that list, see [Which OpenType Math Fonts are Available.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425098/which-opentype-math-fonts-are-available)

Comment: Rather than load an upright font as italic, I’d recommend loading `\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}`, then loading the font as `\setmathfont[range=up]` (or whatever subset it supports).

Comment: @Davislor - Thanks for your suggestions. They led me to replacing the two `\setmathfont` instructions involving the `Bradley Hand Bold` font with the foilowing, much simpler directive: `\setmathfont{Bradley Hand Bold}[range={up,it}]`.