# Switching from PDFLaTeX to LuaLaTeX

Tags: pdftex, luatex, packages, compiling

**Code**

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{microtype}
\DisableLigatures[f]{encoding = T1}
\usepackage{hyperref} % Used in alot of my documents.

\begin{document}
Test.
\end{document}
```

Assume I compile using `pdflatex` (with an up-to-date TeX Live distribution), I then use the setup above.

**Questions**

I have a few questions:

1. Is `\usepackage{inputenc}` needed at all when compiling using `pdflatex`?
2. When kind of packages should I load and how do I setup the font properly if I want to compile using `lualatex`?

Is the following correct and if not, how do I do it in a correct way?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{danish}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures = TeX}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\setmainfont[
  BoldFont       = texgyrepagella-bold.otf,
  ItalicFont     = texgyrepagella-italic.otf,
  BoldItalicFont = texgyrepagella-bolditalic.otf
]{texgyrepagella-regular.otf}
\usepackage{hyperref} % Used in alot of my documents.

\begin{document}
Test.
\end{document}
```

Also, is the loading-order of the packages of any importance? (I know that [`hyperref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) should almost always be loaded as the last package but apart from that?)

**Update**

In case I want to remove all ligatures, is the following then the correct way to do it?

```
\addfontfeature{
  Ligatures = {
    RequiredOff,
    CommonOff,
    ContextualOff,
    RareOff,
    HistoricOff,
    TeXOff
  }
}
```

instead of

```
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures = TeX}
```

I found it in Table 11 at the bottom of page 42 of the [`fontspec` manual](https://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/unicodetex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.pdf#page=42).

Comment: Package `inputenc` is only needed for `pdflatex` if you use an old encoding, like `latin1`. `utf8'  is the default.

Comment: @Teepeemm Some of it is useful to me but I still would like to know exactly how my setup for packages and fonts should be.

Comment: This asks different questions to the marked duplicate.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Thank you, Andrew! I thought so too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the OpenType math font and not package `mathpazo`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{danish}
\usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[
Extension      = .otf,
UprightFont    = *-regular,
BoldFont       = *-bold,
ItalicFont     = *-italic,
BoldItalicFont = *-bolditalic,
Ligatures      = {CommonOff,TeXOff}%   no ligatures
]{texgyrepagella}

\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}
\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}[version=bold,RawFeature={embolden=2}]

\usepackage{hyperref} % Used in alot of my documents.

\begin{document}
    Test. -- ---  ff fl fi
    $y=f(x)$ \boldmath $y=\int_1^2f(x)\symup{d}x$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How do I remove all ligatures? Is what I've added at the bottom of the question correct?

Comment: Is there a reason why you used `RawFeature` instead of `FakeBold=2?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg - `\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures = TeX,NoCommon}`. All other ligature features are not enabled by default. The "TeX" ligatures (e.g., en-dashes and em-dashes) would not be considered to be real ligatures by most folk outside the TeX world. But if you don't want to enable the creation of en-  and em-dashes by typing `--` and `---`, respectively, then by all means run `\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures = NoTeX,NoCommon}`.

Comment: @Mico Thank you very much, but unfortunately `NoCommon` isn't valid; `! LaTeX Error: The key 'fontspec-opentype/NoCommon' is unknown and is being ignored.`. Should it be `\addfontfeature{Ligatures = TeX, NoCommon}`, i.e. `\addfontfeature` instead of `\defaultfontfeatures`?

Comment: @MarcelKrüger: No, there was no reason ...

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: See edited answer for no ligatures

Comment: @SvendTveskæg - My bad. I omitted a pair of curly braces. `\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures = {TeX,NoCommon}}` works as expected.

Comment: @Mico When I use your suggestion on one of my 'real' documents, I get the warning `Package fontspec Warning: OpenType feature 'Ligatures=TeX,CommonOff' (liga) not available for font 'texgyrepagella-math' with script 'Math' and language 'Default'.`. However, if I use `\addfontfeature{Ligatures = {TeX, CommonOff}}` I get no warnings.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: a math font has no special ligatures.

Comment: @user187802 I see! Is it then correct to add `Ligatures = {TeX,CommonOff}` as an option to `\setmainfont` (almost what you already did)?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: Don't use the Ligature option for math! With my code you do not get a warning. And yes you can add it to `\setmainfont`

Comment: @SvendTveskæg - For the record: Earlier today, I recommended writing `Ligatures = {TeX,NoCommon}`, *not* `Ligatures=TeX,CommonOff`. If nothing else, you would appear to be missing a pair of curly braces.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for the reminder regarding the barces. I used `CommonOff` because that's given in the manual. `:-)`

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest the following changes: use `fontspec` with suitable OpenType font (`TeXGyre Pagella` mimics Palatino fairly well), and use `unicode-math` with suitable math font (again, `TeXGyre Pagella Math` works fine, IMO it looks better than `mathpazo`, which borrows some glyphs from Computer Modern, and they look different from Palatino). You don't have to drop `babel`, it works fine. Also, `LuaLaTeX` have a very nice font search engine, so in most cases it's sufficient to use the human readable font family name in order to find it.

Also, when using one font will become boring, you could find many `unicode-math` compatible math fonts in this nice question: [Which OpenType Math fonts are available?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425098/which-opentype-math-fonts-are-available)

An example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX,NoCommon}}
\setmainfont{TeXGyre Pagella}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeXGyre Pagella Math}

\usepackage{hyperref} % Used in alot of my documents.

\begin{document}
Test. Difficult \emph{test}. Some math --- 
\[
  \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}dx = \sqrt{\pi}.
\]
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]