# Math and Text Font Size Not the Same

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontsize, math-fonts

This is a follow-up question to [Switching from PDFLaTeX to LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/659620/switching-from-pdflatex-to-lualatex). Using user187802's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/659625/15874), I have the following setup:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
  Extension      = .otf,
  UprightFont    = *-regular,
  BoldFont       = *-bold,
  ItalicFont     = *-italic,
  BoldItalicFont = *-bolditalic,
  Ligatures      = {
    TeX,
    CommonOff
  }
]{NewCM10}

\usepackage[
  math-style   = TeX,
  warnings-off = {
    mathtools-colon
  }
]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Regular.otf}
\setmathfont[
  version  = bold,
  FakeBold = 2
]{NewCMMath-Regular.otf}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{danish}

\begin{document}

Test.\footnote{`12345' versus `$12345$'}

\end{document}
```

[image: footnote]

As can be seen in the output, neither the font size nor the font boldness in text mode and math mode are the same. (It doesn't just occur in footnotes but elsewhere the difference is more subtle.)

How can I get the exact same font size and font boldness for text mode and math mode when using the `NewCM10` font?

Comment: do you want to change math fonts at all?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hmm ... Not really.

Comment: By default, if you don't load uncode-math, you would get the same math fonts as pdflatex `lmodern` package, or you could re-instate the computer modern fonts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, digits scale differently in NewCM-Math.

You can assign the text font to the digits.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
  Extension      = .otf,
  UprightFont    = *-Regular,
  BoldFont       = *-Bold,
  ItalicFont     = *-Italic,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
  Ligatures = {
    TeX,
    CommonOff
  },
  NFSSFamily=ncm,
]{NewCM10}

\usepackage[
  math-style = TeX,
  warnings-off = {
    mathtools-colon
  }
]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Regular.otf}
\setmathfont[
  version = bold,
  FakeBold = 4,
]{NewCMMath-Regular.otf}

\setdefaultlanguage{danish}

% fix digits
\DeclareSymbolFont{textdigits}{TU}{ncm}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{textdigits}{bold}{TU}{ncm}{b}{n}

\Umathcode`0="7 \symtextdigits `0
\Umathcode`1="7 \symtextdigits `1
\Umathcode`2="7 \symtextdigits `2
\Umathcode`3="7 \symtextdigits `3
\Umathcode`4="7 \symtextdigits `4
\Umathcode`5="7 \symtextdigits `5
\Umathcode`6="7 \symtextdigits `6
\Umathcode`7="7 \symtextdigits `7
\Umathcode`8="7 \symtextdigits `8
\Umathcode`9="7 \symtextdigits `9

\newcommand{\test}{%
  12345 versus $12345$\par
  \sbox0{12345}\the\wd0\ versus \sbox0{$12345$}\the\wd0\par
}


\begin{document}

\test {\bfseries\boldmath\test}

\bigskip

{\footnotesize\test {\bfseries\boldmath\test}}

$a+b=c$

{\boldmath$a+b=c$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without the `\Umathcode` lines, the output is

[image]

Comment: Nice! Is there a reason for loading `\setmathfont[
  version = bold,
  FakeBold = 2
]{NewCMMath-Regular.otf}` twice? Also, is the loading order of the packages of any importance?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg No, leftover… Anyway, I find that `FakeBold=4` is better.

Comment: Thank you very much, Enrico! I was also wondering why the `\ifffalse` `\if` code was there but I see that it was not intended. `:-)`

Comment: @SvendTveskæg I tried with loading `fontsetup` instead of directly choosing the fonts; there are some differences, because `fontsetup` selects optically scaled fonts to some extent; for instance, with `\footnotesize` NewCM08-* is used.

Comment: "Apparently, digits scale differently in NewCM-Math." No it is not the font that does something strange here, it is LaTeX. Another thing: with this solution one will not get ssty variants in superscripts like `$x^2$`.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that LaTeX's Unicode math sets the math Unicode font with `ssty` font feature by very specific way. It uses `+ssty=0` for textstyle, `+ssty=1` for script style etc. I used in OpTeX only `ssty=0`, `ssty=1` etc., without the `+` sign. I am unable to find the documentation of the plus sign in this font feature (the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/features_pt#ssty doesn't mention this) but I see that if it is used then the definitive variant of letters are selected not by the number specified for this feature, but by the size used for the font.

Compare:

```
LaTeX: [NewCMMath-Regular.otf]:mode=base;script=math;language=dflt;+ssty=0; at 8.0pt
OpTeX: [NewCMMath-Regular]:mode=base;script=math;ssty=0;mathsize=1; at 8.0pt
```

LaTeX selects script alternative shapes for the digits 1234 in loaded font, OpTeX selects basic shapes scaled to 8pt, which looks better in the footnote size. OpTeX selects script alternative shapes when `ssty=1`, i.e. only when scriptstyle in math mode is used.

Comment: `ssty=0;` is ignored by luaotfload, so you could also simply remove it.

Comment: Interesting, we were discussing in chat how to best avoid ssty here but I had not noticed the + here

Comment: as Marcel just explained in the chat, `+ssty=0;` is the same as `ssty=1;`.

Comment: The question is why there is `+ssty=0`. If this is the same as `ssty=1` why isn't here this explicit syntax. And why LaTeX needs the `ssty=1` here in `\textstyle` math. It seems like puzzlement.

Comment: @wipet Nice answer. Any chance I can make you create a compilable example (with all the code that is needed in the preamble for my document)?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg integrating this in latex is non trivial as latex assumes there is only one mapping of size to font features, not separate maps for textstyle and scriptstyle

Comment: @SvendTveskæg One chance is to use something different than LaTeX:).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Okay. I'm not nearly on your LaTeX level so I just hoped for some easy fix. `:-)`

Comment: @wipet latex is using ssty at small sizes independently of the context, so a 7pt superscript at 10pt base but also a 7pt \textstyle in 7pt footnotes. It has always done this but classcally the footnote text would be using cmr7 so also using wider glyphs so does not show the difference in the question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes I know. But it is question if this concept is correct when we have 99,99 percent Unicode text fonts without optical scaling, but math Unicode fonts have always their three variants of glyphs.

Comment: @wipet no, probably not