# Font Family Selection for LuaLaTeX

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontfamily

This is a follow-up question to "[Math and text font size not the same](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/665118/15874)".

For the `NewCM10` font, egreg uses `NFSSFamily = ncm` when setting the main font and `ncm` in both `\DeclareSymbolFont` and `\SetSymbolFont`.

What should I use when using the `texgyrepagella` font instead of `NewCM10`?

Comment: ncm is arbitrary. you could use "tgp" or "svend" or "blub" instead. (OK not completly arbitrary: better avoid names already in used for other fonts like pcr or pag to avoid they get mixed up.)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Hehehehe. I thought that it was a name that had to be used when using NewComputerModern. `:-)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string `ncm` I used was made up for the occasion. Possibly

```
newcomputermodern
```

would have been better, but you can use essentially whatever you like. If you don't load legacy fonts, no conflict can arise. Be creative.

Comment: Hehehehe. I thought that it was a name that had to be used when using NewComputerModern. :-) Can I then use, say, `NFSSFamily = texgypa` and then `\DeclareSymbolFont{textdigits}{TU}{texgypa}{m}{n} \SetSymbolFont{textdigits}{bold}{TU}{texgypa}{b}{n}` for the `texgyrepagella` font i order to get the exact same numbers in text mode and math mode?

Comment: Yes, that’s fine

Comment: Thanks! By the way, what does `TU` represent, and should it be the same for `NewCM10` and `texgyrepagella`?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg `TU` is the official output encoding for Unicode savvy fonts.