# Why is XeLaTeX not able to detect NewCM10-Regular.otf from .fontspec files?

Tags: xetex

I want to use [`NewCM10-Regular.otf`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/newcomputermodern/otf). It works perfectly with both the Unicode engines when loaded like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{NewCM10-Regular.otf}

\begin{document}
hello world
\end{document}
```

it also works if I embed it in an sty file and load it like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{foo}

\begin{document}
hello world
\end{document}
```

while the `foo.sty` has this:

```
\ProvidesPackage{foo}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{NewCM10-Regular.otf}
```

but this fails if I use a custom `.fontspec` file. So suppose the sty file has:

```
\ProvidesPackage{foo}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{myfont}
```

and in the same folder where my `.tex` and `.sty` are, if I create a `myfont.fontspec` with the following code:

```
\defaultfontfeatures[myfont]{UprightFont = {NewCM10-Regular.otf}}
```

it works with `lualatex`, but not `xelatex`. Interestingly if I change the font from `NewCM10-Regular.otf` to `CharisSIL`, it again works with both the engines. So what's exactly wrong with `xelatex`, `.fontspec` files and `NewCM10-Regular.otf`?

PS: I am using fully updated TL2022 on GNU/Linux.

Comment: Hope this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/665118/math-and-text-font-size-not-the-same/665123#665123 will helps you.

Comment: @MadyYuvi thanks for the reference, but I really don't see any solution for my particular problem in it. Can you please explain what should be done in order to make my code run with XeLaTeX too?

Comment: Your code works well for me, hope the error was related with `OS`, actually `Mac` and `Linux` works based on `case sensitive`, if possible, can you check the same in a `MS-Windows` system.

Comment: use `\defaultfontfeatures[myfont]{Extension = .otf,UprightFont = {NewCM10-Regular}}`, see also https://github.com/latex3/fontspec/issues/480 (I have no idea if this is really new, the documentation does not show an example with the other syntax). The other syntax doesn't work with lualatex correctly either, in the terminal a search throught the database is triggered everytime.

Comment: @MadyYuvi you might have a different distribution probably. With the latest files I am indeed having this problem. Thanks anyways for the suggestions.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ah!! Precisely this was the problem. I hope it gets fixed. Right now I have made the necessary change in my code for it to be cross-engine-compatible. Thanks. An answer would be great for the reference of other users.

Comment: Use the `Extension = .otf` method for both engines, so that both engines work correctly and effficiently.

Comment: @Cicada yes, that's what Ulrike mentioned in her comment. That method indeed seems to work. If you want, you can post this as an answer for the reference of other users.

Comment: You can self-answer and self-accept. Reading the (fontspec) manual is not a deep exercise of skill and knowledge, so I cannot accept credit for that; however, benefiting from the advice of someone who has read the manual is worthwhile, particularly with time constraints, and with big and complex packages.