# Pairing two fonts for antique looking math

Tags: xetex, luatex, typography, math-fonts, asana

How do I pair **Old Standard** (for alphabets and digits) and **Asana-Math** (for the rest of the math) in order to write antique looking math?

Comment: Are you limited to Xe(La)TeX, or can you also work with Lua(La)TeX?

Comment: Any kind of solution is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? Sample text taken from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/425098/208544).

[image: sample]

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator\Res{Res}
\newcommand*\diff{\mathop{}\!\mathup{d}}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Old Standard}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\setmathfont{Old Standard Italic}[range=it]
\setmathfont{Old Standard}[range=up]
\setmathfont{Old Standard Bold Italic}[range=bfit]

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Residue theorem]
  Let $f$ be analytic in the region $G$ except for the isolated
  singularities $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_m$. If $\gamma$ is a closed
  rectifiable curve in $G$ which does not pass through any of the
  points $a_k$ and if $\gamma\approx 0$ in $G$, then
  \[
    \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int\limits_\gamma f\Bigl(x^{\mathbf{N}\in\mathbb{C}^{N\times 10}}\Bigr)
    = \sum_{k=1}^m n(\gamma;a_k)\Res(f;a_k)\,.
  \]
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Maximum modulus]
  Let $G$ be a bounded open set in $\BbbC$ and suppose that $f$ is a
  continuous function on $G^-$ which is analytic in $G$. Then
  \[
    \max\{\, |f(z)|:z\in G^- \,\} = \max\{\, |f(z)|:z\in \partial G \,\}\,.
  \]
\end{theorem}

First some large operators both in text:
$\iiint\limits_{Q}f(x,y,z) \diff x \diff y \diff z$
and
$\prod_{\gamma\in\Gamma_{\bar{C}}}\partial(\tilde{X}_\gamma)$;\
and also on display
\[
  \iiiint\limits_{Q}f(w,x,y,z) \diff w \diff x \diff y \diff z
  \leq
  \oint_{\partial Q} f'\Biggl(\max\Biggl\{
  \frac{\Vert w\Vert}{\vert w^2+x^2\vert};
  \frac{\Vert z\Vert}{\vert y^2+z^2\vert};
  \frac{\Vert w\oplus z\Vert}{\vert x\oplus y\vert}
  \Biggr\}\Biggr)\,.
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Damn it! This is perfect! Thank you!