# How to install any font from the latex font catalog on windows?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, xetex, miktex, installing-fonts

I use Windows 11, miktex 4.9 and texstudio. And I would like to know how to install fonts from the font catalog available at https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/.

All fonts that install using pdflatex do not give an error. I only use fonts that I download from the CTAN that the catalog directs and using xelatex, but I use fonts that are supported by the mathematical environment.

So, I want to know how to install diverse fonts from the font catalog in pdflatex, xelatex and install fonts that have math support, can someone help me?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please translate your question into English. Please also focus on a specific problem. Not all fonts are installed in the same way. Some can be installed via your tex distribution, some can't. And with xelatex you can use system fonts from your operating system.

Comment: Sorry a part of the text was not translated

Comment: "diverse fonts" is confusing me.  Is there a specific font you want to install?  What files do you have related to that font?  Once it's installed, using it is a different question, and would depend on whether you're wanting pdflatex or xelatex.

Answer (score 2):

If the fonts are in TrueType or OpenType format, download them (from their own project page, or from CTAN), select the font files in the download folder (in `.ttf`, `.ttc`, `.otf` or `.otc` format) right-click, and “Install for All Users.” Installing only for your own user account, without administrator privileges, would put the files in a hidden directory of your user folder that TeX Live doesn’t know about.

If what you actually want is to get Office Equation Editor to use a font like TeX’s default, download and install [New Computer Modern.](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/newcomputermodern/otf)

If it’s a legacy 8-bit font, you can’t (without heroic efforts at retrocomputing).  Although Windows understands one type of font file from the ’90s that PDFTeX still uses (Adobe PostScript Type 1, `.pfb` plus `.afm`), it doesn’t support any TeX character sets or font metrics.

Most popular TeX fonts have an OpenType/Truetype fork, or else are clones of a commercial font that’s available for Windows.  For math fonts, [we maintain a list here.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425098/which-opentype-math-fonts-are-available)

Comment: So it's only possible to use fonts from the font catalog in latex by downloading them from CTAN and installing them (by placing them in a folder and using commands to access that folder), right?

Comment: @LeonardoGonçalves I’m unclear what you mean. There are several ways to use them in TeX. I took you as asking how to use them from different Windows apps.

Comment: Guys after a few attempts I got it here. I actually found conflict problems between packages, but I managed to put the heuristic source here, the one I wanted, thanks. And very nice font catalog, very good, thank you!!!