# What font uses \mathbb?

Tags: fonts

My question is very simple I want to use the the LaTeX Math Black Board Font for a commercial design in Inkscape (does no matter file format), but don't know font name, nor download link.

Comment: https://ctan.org/pkg/cmathbb but you'd be better off with any of the open type math fonts https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425098/which-opentype-math-fonts-are-available

Comment: @DG' Where are the black board variants

Comment: What do you mean? In the font, check the glyphs

Comment: @DG' You mean I have to use the blackboard unicode characters?

Comment: Or, you could just set the symbols you need in latex and import the pdf as paths in Inkscape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no “mathbb” font. Maybe you're referring to the one you get with `amsfonts`.

[image]

The letters are in their standard ASCII slot in the Type1 font

```
/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/symbols/msbm10.pfb
```

The part before `texmf-dist` is system dependent, you should be able to find the file in your distribution by issuing

```
kpsewhich msbm10.pfb
```

from the command line. The file is also available on CTAN

https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/amsfonts/pfb

I don't know whether you can use Type1 fonts in Inkscape, but you should be able to find your way.

Answer (score 2):

Generate a pdf containing the symbols you need:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
$\mathbb{ABCXYZ}$
\end{document}
```

And import the result in Inkscape:

[image]