# LuaLaTeX sans serif math font unicode greek

Tags: fonts, luatex, greek, sans-serif

I know there are a lot of posts about this here on tex.stackexchange but all I can find are pretty old (almost ~ 5-10 years old by now) and I'm not sure if they still apply.

So is there a way to use a sans serif font for the normal text characters in math mode?

```tex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[version=bold,FakeBold={3}]
\setoperatorfont\mathsf

\begin{document}
    normal text

    $(a+\rho_i)^2 = a^2 + 2a\rho_i \rho_i^2 \quad \min\text{ text in math}$
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code above]

In this example it would be an issue for the `i` indices and the `a` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set any [OpenType math font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425098/which-opentype-math-fonts-are-available) using `unicode-math`.  it’s the simplest way.

The `unicode-math` package also lets you take Greek letters from another font with, *e.g.* `\setmathfont[range=it/{Greek, greek}]{CMU Sans Serif Italic}`, but all OpenType math fonts support Greek.

There are also solutions using `mathastext` and `mathspec`, or you could load `fontspec` over any legacy 8-bit sans-serif math package.

Comment: Alright, I'll have a look at the various fonts available. Note: For your `\setmathexamle` I get an error `missing number`. Seems like the `range` argument isn't completely correct.

Comment: @atticus Whoops! You got me. Should work now. There’are separate commands for upright, bold italic, and bold upright, should you need them. But any OpenType math font has those.

Comment: In these tables like in https://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/fonts/firamath/firamath-specimen.pdf do you know what it means if a glyph is grayed out? Does this mean it is not available (and I need to search for a font which includes that glyph)?

Comment: @atticus I believe that’s correct, but all the Greek letters used in math are available. The upright (`\symup`) alphabet is in the Greek and Coptic code block, which is missing only Coptic, and the other alphabets, including the default, are in Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols.

Comment: @atticus It does appear to be lacking `\mathcal` or `\mathscr`, however.

Answer (score 1):

To get a sans serif font you should set a sans serif font; Latin Modern isn't.
You need a font with math support. See: [Which OpenType Math fonts are available?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425098/which-opentype-math-fonts-are-available).

For example, with `FiraMath-Regular`:

```tex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setoperatorfont\symup
\setmathfont{FiraMath-Regular}

\begin{document}
    normal text

    $(a+\rho_i)^2 = a^2 + 2a\rho_i \rho_i^2 \quad \min\text{ text in math}$

\end{document}
```

This gives:
[image: Code with FiraMath-Regular font]

I set `\setoperatorfont\symup` to handle operator (like `\min`) with `unicode-math`.

Comment: Oh the `symup` note is a nice one. Sadly `FiraMath-Regular` seems to be lacking the `\bigcup` and `\setminus` symbols. But I get I have to look further into different fonts.