Using mathastext with a custom font
I am using a custom corporate font in my document and I would like the math to appear the same as the main body font. I don't want any sign of roman font, but it's appearing in math despite my efforts.
Please see this overleaf project for the MWE: https://www.overleaf.com/read/tntkpmhtqhbd#162f19

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{CustomBook}

\setsansfont[
  UprightFont={*Book},
  ItalicFont={*BookItalic},
  BoldFont={*Medium},
  BoldItalicFont={*MediumItalic},
]{Custom}

\setmonofont{CMUTypewriterTextLight} % monospace

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{\sfdefault}

% \usepackage{unicode-math}
% \usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage[subdued]{mathastext}
\Mathastext[sans]

\begin{document}

Hello World. The main fonts works the way I want.

\texttt{The tt works the way I want}

$y = mx+b \pi is = 3.1416$  The math does not work. I would like it to use the same font as the main body

\end{document}

EDIT: Here is an additional example which uses a font available in TeXLive:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

% \setmainfont{CustomBook}

% \setsansfont[
%   UprightFont={*Book},
%   ItalicFont={*BookItalic},
%   BoldFont={*Medium},
%   BoldItalicFont={*MediumItalic},
% ]{Custom}


\setsansfont{cmunb}[        %CMU Bright for text
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*mr,
    ItalicFont=*mo,
    BoldFont=*sr, % semibold  % swap bold with semibold
    BoldItalicFont=*so, % semibold oblique
    NFSSFamily=cmbr
    ]

\setmonofont{CMUTypewriterTextLight} % monospace

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{\sfdefault}

% \usepackage{unicode-math}
% \usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage[subdued]{mathastext}  % subdued makes no difference
\Mathastext[sans]

\begin{document}

Hello World. The main fonts works the way I want.

\texttt{The tt works the way I want}

$y = mx+b \pi is = 3.1416$  The math does not work. I would like it to use the same font as the main body

\end{document}


from the manual: subdued means the effect of the package is limited to non-default maths versions, but you are using only the default version, so the package rightly makes no changes. moreover, note that support for unicode engines and fonts is described as 'partial', so you should not expect this to work flawlessly. 'partial' here means 'compared with support for 7/8bit fonts', but that support will not change all maths. the package only substitutes the main font for certain elements of maths because text fonts don't provide symbols, greek (maths symbols as opposed to text) etc.

can you reproduce with a font in texlive? right now, only somebody with CustomBook can reproduce this.

I uploaded the font to the project, I will DM you a link to edit the project, if you are willing

@cfr  https://www.overleaf.com/8666854694qptwxrpmntqk#bdc19f

questions should be self-contained, so they remain useful to future readers. can you really not reproduce this with a font we all have?

I can try.. Also FWIW, I am using MiKTeX on my local machine, and it appears to work on the letters, but not numbers and symbols (they remain roman).

from the docs: you need the no-math option for fontspec. see also page 16: However mathastext applies only to (a subset of) the 32-127 ascii range, and optionally to Greek letters, but for the latter only if provided via “TEX fonts” such as Euler, Symbol or LGR-encoded fonts. It does not know how to use a given Unicode font simultaneously for Latin and Greek letters. so what you see with miktex is probably getting close to what you can expect, though you might be able to get numbers working.

@cfr I added no-math and changed the font to one available in tex live, still not what I'm looking for unfortunately.

can you edit your example accordingly?

@cfr done, thank you very much

If your custom font doesn't have a math font, how about combining it with a sans serif math font instead? This way you'll avoid all the serif and still have all the math symbols etc.

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/425099/36296 for an overview of available math fonts. There aren't a lot of sans serif ones, but still a couple you could try to see if they work with your custom font.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz my follow-up question was going to be combining symbols from a math font with my corporate font. My documents aren't terribly math heavy though, and I'd like the alphanumeric characters to match my main body.

You can set up the text upright and italic, then as you don't have too many math symbols, just define them as needed.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

% \setmainfont{CustomBook}

% \setsansfont[
%   UprightFont={*Book},
%   ItalicFont={*BookItalic},
%   BoldFont={*Medium},
%   BoldItalicFont={*MediumItalic},
% ]{Custom}


\setsansfont{cmunb}[        %CMU Bright for text
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*mr,
    ItalicFont=*mo,
    BoldFont=*sr, % semibold  % swap bold with semibold
    BoldItalicFont=*so, % semibold oblique
    NFSSFamily=cmbr
    ]

\setmonofont{CMUTypewriterTextLight} % monospace

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{\sfdefault}

\SetSymbolFont{operators}{normal}{TU}{cmbr}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{normal}{TU}{cmbr}{m}{it}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \Umathchardef \pi 0 \symletters "03C0
  }

\begin{document}

Hello World. The main fonts works the way I want.

\texttt{The tt works the way I want}

$y = mx+b \pi is = 3.1416$  The math does not work. I would like it to use the same font as the main body

\end{document}


This works well, considering that cmbright is quite close to my corporate font. Do you know how I could adopt alphanumeric characters from my corporate font in math mode?

@likethevegetable just do exactly as shown here, using your other font instead of cmunb

Thank you--I just had to declare an NFSSFamily name for my custom font and replace cmbr.
